# Idiom for pairwise iteration through a sorted collection

Tags: java, collections

Is there a Java idiom for pairwise iteration through the elements of a sorted `Collection`? By that I mean that each iteration has access to one element of the collection and the next element of the collection?

For sorted `List`s (and arrays), it can be done using an index into the collection:

```
 final int n = list.size();
 assert 2 <= n;
 for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    final Thing thing1 = list.get(i);
    final Thing thing2 = list.get(i+1);
    operateOnAdjacentPair(thing1, thing2);
 }
```

But what about `SortedSet`? (for `SortedMap` you can use its `entrySet()`, which is equivalent to the `SortedSet` case).

---

So, for example, if your sorted set contained the values {1, 2, 3, 4}, the iterations would be for the pairs (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply implement it the following way (and apply similar strategy towards other collections):

```
Iterator<Thing> iter = set.iterator();
Thing previous = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    final Thing current = iter.next();
    operateOnAdjacentPair(previous, current);
    previous = current;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Iterator<Thing> thingerator = coll.iterator();
if (thingerator.hasNext()) {
    Thing thing1 = thingerator.next();
    while (thingerator.hasNext()) {
      final Thing thing2 = thingerator.next();
      doStuffToThings(thing1, thing2);

      thing1 = thing2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your suggestion iterates through only half the pairs, because each iteration advances by 2 elements.

Comment: @Raedwald This one is stepping through (1,2)(3,4)... just as you indicated in the question.

Comment: No, look at the example I gave for `List`.

Comment: I modified my answer to step by one at a time ([1,2], [2, 3], [3, 4]).

Answer (score 1):

Write an implementation of Iterator, e.g. (just writing off the top of my head, so code may not work as is)

```
public class PairwiseIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>> {
    private final Iterator<T> elements;
    private T last;

    public PairwiseIterator(Collection<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements.iterator();
        last = elements.hasNext() ? elements.next() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return elements.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {
        List<T> result = ImmutableList.of(last, elements.next());
        last = result.get(1);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not allowed with this iterator");
    }

    public static <U> Iterable<List<U>> iterable(final Collection<U> elements) {
        return new Iterable() {
            public Iterator<U> iterator() {
                return new PairwiseIterator(elements);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I probably don't have the types exactly right, but the 'iterable' method makes it easy to use in foreach constructs:

```
for(List<String> pair : PairwiseIterator.iterable(orderedSetOfStrings)) {
    // ... do what you need to ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Set`s (and other non-indexable collections) you will need to use their [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)s as returned by the [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) method of `Collection`:

```
Iterator<Thing> iter = set.iterator();
Thing thing1 = iter.next();  // might want to check if this exists
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Thing thing2 = iter.next();
    operateOnAdjacentPair(thing1, thing2);
    thing1 = thing2;
}
```

You can do the same for `Map`s, using the `Iterator` of their [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)s.

---

Now that I understand your question better, you could also try this:

```
Iterator<Thing> iter1 = set.iterator(), iter2 = set.iterator();

if (iter2.hasNext())
    iter2.next();  // burn first element

while (iter2.hasNext()) {
    final Thing thing1 = iter1.next();
    final Thing thing2 = iter2.next();
    operateOnAdjacentPair(thing1, thing2);
}
```

Comment: I believe your suggestion iterates through only half the pairs, because each iteration advances by 2 elements.

Comment: @Raedwald Yes you're right, I misunderstood your example. Should be all set now. I also added another alternative, now that I understand what you were really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Guava offers a PeekingIterator which can be used for this:

```java
PeekingIterator<Thing> iter = 
    Iterators.peekingIterator(set.iterator());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    final Thing thing1 = iter.next();
　　 if (iter.hasNext()) { // don't forget this one
        operateOnAdjacentPair(thing1, iter.peek());
    }
}
```

When the loop code becomes more complex, the benefit becomes more evident, maybe.

Comment: This is a [tag:java] question, not a [tag:guava] question.