# Collect successive pairs from a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given an object or primitive stream such as `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }`,  how can I most elegantly transform it into given form (assuming, of course, I've defined class `Pair`)?

`{ new Pair(0, 1), new Pair(1, 2), new Pair(2, 3), new Pair(3, 4) }`

Comment: The term from FP is "partition", but I'm not finding a method with the desired semantics in Java. It has partitioning on a predicate.

Comment: Typically the spliterator in JDK 8 is thought for traversing and partitioning purposes. I will try to come up with an example also.

Comment: `list.stream().map(i -> new Pair(i, i+1));`

Comment: For the equivalent non streams question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453022/idiom-for-pairwise-iteration-through-a-sorted-collection

Comment: By the way, some folks use either implementation of [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) as a Pair class. (Granted, some might consider that a hack, but using a built-in class is handy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is built-in support for this in the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature:

```java
Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
        .gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2))
        .map(list -> new Pair(list.get(0), list.get(1)))
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int)) gatherer to convert the initial `Stream<Integer>` (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`) to a pairwise `Stream<List<Integer>>` (`[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`).  Each of these lists is then transformed to a `Pair` using the existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a given size, where each subsequent window includes all elements of the previous window except for the least recent, and adds the next element in the stream. […]
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows2 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2)).toList();
>
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows6 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(6)).toList();
> ```

Answer (score 84):

The Java 8 streams library is primarily geared toward splitting streams into smaller chunks for parallel processing, so stateful pipeline stages are quite limited, and doing things like getting the index of the current stream element and accessing adjacent stream elements are not supported.

A typical way to solve these problems, with some limitations, of course, is to drive the stream by indexes and rely on having the values being processed in some random-access data structure like an ArrayList from which the elements can be retrieved. If the values were in `arrayList`, one could generate the pairs as requested by doing something like this:

```
    IntStream.range(1, arrayList.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> new Pair(arrayList.get(i-1), arrayList.get(i)))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Of course the limitation is that the input cannot be an infinite stream. This pipeline can be run in parallel, though.

Comment: "The input cannot be an infinite stream." Actually, the input cannot be a stream at all. The input (`arrayList`) is in fact a collection, which is why I didn't mark it as the answer. (But congrats on your gold badge!)

Comment: is there a way in streams to conditionally skip next iteration i.e. increment forEach or mapToObj index to i+2 instead of i+1? Is that is not a recommended use case for streams or functional programming in java?

Answer (score 39):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which extends standard streams provides a [`pairMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#pairMap-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method for all stream types. For primitive streams it does not change the stream type, but can be used to make some calculations. Most common usage is to calculate differences:

```
int[] pairwiseDiffs = IntStreamEx.of(input).pairMap((a, b) -> (b-a)).toArray();
```

For object stream you can create any other object type. My library does not provide any new user-visible data structures like `Pair` (that's the part of library concept). However if you have your own `Pair` class and want to use it, you can do the following:

```
Stream<Pair> pairs = IntStreamEx.of(input).boxed().pairMap(Pair::new);
```

Or if you already have some `Stream`:

```
Stream<Pair> pairs = StreamEx.of(stream).pairMap(Pair::new);
```

This functionality is implemented using [custom spliterator](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/PairSpliterator.java). It has quite low overhead and can parallelize nicely. Of course it works with any stream source, not just random access list/array like many other solutions. In many tests it performs really well. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/336df22ea21316feccf1) a JMH benchmark where we find all input values preceding a larger value using different approaches (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30089761/4856258) question).

Comment: Thank you! The more I study this library, the more I love it. I might finally start using streams. (`StreamEx` implements `Iterable`! Hurrah!)

Comment: To make your answer 100% complete, could you show how to wrap a `Stream` into a `StreamEx`?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: just use [`StreamEx.of(stream)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#of-java.util.stream.Stream-). There are other convenient static methods to create the stream from `Collection`, array, `Reader`, etc. Edited the answer.

Comment: @TagirValeev is `pairMap` ordered on sequental streams? Actually, I would like to have forPairsOrdered(), but as there is no such method, can I simulate it somehow? `stream.ordered().forPairs()` or `stream().pairMap().forEachOrdered()`?

Comment: @AskarKalykov, the `pairMap` is the intermediate operation with non-interfering stateless mapper function, the ordering is not specified for it in the same way as for simple `map`. The `forPairs` is unordered by specification, but unordered operations are de-facto ordered for sequential streams. It would be nice if you formulate your original problem as separate stackoverflow question to provide more context.

Answer (score 23):

You can do this with the Stream.reduce() method (I haven't seen any other answers using this technique).

```
public static <T> List<Pair<T, T>> consecutive(List<T> list) {
    List<Pair<T, T>> pairs = new LinkedList<>();
    list.stream().reduce((a, b) -> {
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(a, b));
        return b;
    });
    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: It would return (1,2) (2,3) instead of (1,2) (3,4). Also I'm not sure if it would be applied in order (certainly there's no guarantee of that).

Comment: Please check the question, that is the intended behaviour @Aleksandr Dubinsky

Comment: Ahh, yes, sorry. And to think, I wrote it.

Comment: The order seems to be guaranted according to [Is .collect guaranteed to be ordered on parallel streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710999/is-collect-guaranteed-to-be-ordered-on-parallel-streams) and [How to ensure order of processing in java8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams)

Comment: This is a very smart idea! The only problem I would see in this approach is that the reduction function is not *pure* (it depends on the external `pairs` object). Therefore, if ran concurrently, its semantic correctness is not ensured. One possible solution would be to use a thread-safe data structure, such as `Vector`.

Comment: I like the idea, except for the construction of a new list, which is necessary because `reduce` is a terminal operation. Should be able to do this lazily.

Answer (score 18):

This is not elegant, it's a hackish solution, but works for infinite streams

```
Stream<Pair> pairStream = Stream.iterate(0, (i) -> i + 1).map( // natural numbers
    new Function<Integer, Pair>() {
        Integer previous;

        @Override
        public Pair apply(Integer integer) {
            Pair pair = null;
            if (previous != null) pair = new Pair(previous, integer);
            previous = integer;
            return pair;
        }
    }).skip(1); // drop first null
```

Now you can limit your stream to the length you want

```
pairStream.limit(1_000_000).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

**P.S.** I hope there is better solution, something like clojure `(partition 2 1 stream)`

Comment: Kudos for pointing out that anonymous classes are a sometimes useful alternative to lambdas.

Comment: how will this deal with parallel streams?

Comment: @aepurniet I assume it won't work correctly. According to the `parallelStream` doc: "To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters must be non-interfering, and in most cases must be stateless"

Comment: This is completely contrary to the design of the streams framework and directly violates the contract of the map API, as the anonymous function is *not* stateless.  Try running this with a parallel stream and more data so the stream framework creates more working threads, and you will see the result: infrequent random "errors" almost impossible to reproduce and difficult to detect until you have data enough (in production?).  This can be disastrous.

Comment: @MarioRossi The Streams framework does not exist to **only** write parallel code. Its butt, unfortunately, sits on two sides of the fence, and many programmers use it to write sequential code. There are even built-in methods that cannot be parallelized (such as `skip`).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky You are incorrect about limit/skip being parallelizable; the implementation provided in JDK does in fact work in parallel.  Because the operation is tied to encounter order, parallelization may not always provide a performance benefit, but in high-Q situations, it can.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Last time I checked, parallel `skip` would skip a random element. I'd needed to use `forEachOrdered` (instead of`forEach`) as the terminal operation, which made my short pipeline serial. There was no facility to say "I need this part of the pipeline ordered, and this part parallel." (The API preposterously ignores the ordering of calls to `parallel`, `ordered`, `unordered`, and `forEach`.) I concede an ordered, parallel pipeline that terminates in a reduction could see correct behavior from skip. But I've given up on Streams and don't use them, especially for parallelism.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Incorrect.  It may skip a random element if the stream is *unordered* (has no defined encounter order, so logically there *is* no "first" or "nth" element, just elements.)  But whether the stream is ordered or unordered, skip has always been able to work in parallel.  There's just less parallelism to extract if the stream is ordered, but its still parallel.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I do not want to waste the time of someone of your stature. You are right. (I attempted to admit that in my last comment, oh well.) Streams suck nevertheless. (Useless, random, surprising behavior instead of an exception?) Unfortunately, I cannot edit my original comment, except to delete it and re-write it.

Comment: You can eliminate the parallel issues with `skip` by replacing it with `filter(p -> p != null)`. That doesn't take care of the issues with using a stateful mapper, but still.

Answer (score 17):

I've implemented a spliterator wrapper which takes every `n` elements `T` from the original spliterator and produces `List<T>`:

```
public class ConsecutiveSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<List<T>> {

    private final Spliterator<T> wrappedSpliterator;

    private final int n;

    private final Deque<T> deque;

    private final Consumer<T> dequeConsumer;

    public ConsecutiveSpliterator(Spliterator<T> wrappedSpliterator, int n) {
        this.wrappedSpliterator = wrappedSpliterator;
        this.n = n;
        this.deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.dequeConsumer = deque::addLast;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<T>> action) {
        deque.pollFirst();
        fillDeque();
        if (deque.size() == n) {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(deque);
            action.accept(list);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void fillDeque() {
        while (deque.size() < n && wrappedSpliterator.tryAdvance(dequeConsumer))
            ;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<List<T>> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return wrappedSpliterator.estimateSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return wrappedSpliterator.characteristics();
    }
}
```

Following method may be used to create a consecutive stream:

```
public <E> Stream<List<E>> consecutiveStream(Stream<E> stream, int n) {
    Spliterator<E> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
    Spliterator<List<E>> wrapper = new ConsecutiveSpliterator<>(spliterator, n);
    return StreamSupport.stream(wrapper, false);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
consecutiveStream(Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 2)
    .map(list -> new Pair(list.get(0), list.get(1)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Does that repeat every element twice?

Comment: Nope. It creates a new stream containing `List<E>` elements. Each list contains `n` consecutive elements from the original stream. Check it yourself ;)

Comment: Could you modify your answer so that every element (except the first and last) is repeated?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that elements should be repeated. I've fixed my solution.

Comment: +1 I think this is good work and should be generalized to any step size in addition to the partition size. There is a lot of need for a `(partition size step)` function and this is about the best way to get it.

Comment: Consider using `ArrayDeque` for performance, in preference to `LinkedList`.

Comment: The value assigned to `dequeConsumer` (`new Consumer<T>() ...`) is somewhat unnecessarily wordy for Java 8.  It can be replaced with `deque::addLast` which is a lot clearer.

Comment: If `step` parameter should be also taken into account, just replace `deque.pollFirst();` statement with `for (int i = 0; i < step && deque.pollFirst() != null; ++i) {}` loop

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) (I contribute to this library), using the sliding operator.

```
  LazyFutureStream.of( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
                  .sliding(2)
                  .map(Pair::new);
```

Or

```
   ReactiveSeq.of( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
                  .sliding(2)
                  .map(Pair::new);
```

Assuming the Pair constructor can accept a Collection with 2 elements.

If you wanted to group by 4, and increment by 2 that is also supported.

```
     ReactiveSeq.rangeLong( 0L,Long.MAX_VALUE)
                .sliding(4,2)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Equivalant static methods for creating a sliding view over java.util.stream.Stream are also provided in cyclops-streams [StreamUtils](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-RC2.2/com/aol/cyclops/util/stream/StreamUtils.html) class.

```
       StreamUtils.sliding(Stream.of(1,2,3,4),2)
                  .map(Pair::new);
```

Note :- for single-threaded operation ReactiveSeq would be more appropriate. LazyFutureStream extends ReactiveSeq but is primarily geared for concurrent / parallel use (it is a Stream of Futures).

LazyFutureStream extends ReactiveSeq which extends Seq from the awesome jOOλ (which extends java.util.stream.Stream), so the solutions Lukas' presents would also work with either Stream type. For anyone interested the primary differences between the window / sliding operators are the obvious  relative power / complexity trade off and suitability for use with infinite streams (sliding doesn't consume the stream, but buffers as it flows).

Comment: This way you obtain [(0,1)(2,3) ...] but the question asks [(0,1)(1,2) ...]. Please see my answer with RxJava...

Comment: You are right, my bad, I misread the question - the sliding operator is the correct one to use here. I'll update my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[`Streams.zip(..)` is available in Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-), for those who depend on it.

Example:

```
Streams.zip(list.stream(),
            list.stream().skip(1),
            (a, b) -> System.out.printf("%s %s\n", a, b));
```

Answer (score 5):

The [proton-pack library](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) provides the windowed functionnality. Given a Pair class and a Stream, you can do it like this:

```
Stream<Integer> st = Stream.iterate(0 , x -> x + 1);
Stream<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = StreamUtils.windowed(st, 2, 1)
                                                  .map(l -> new Pair<>(l.get(0), l.get(1)))
                                                  .moreStreamOps(...);
```

Now the `pairs` stream contains:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, ...) and so on
```

Comment: However, it looks like you need to create `st` twice! Can this library solve the problem using a single stream?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I don't think so it's available with the current spliterators. I submitted an issue https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/issues/9

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The `windowed` functionality has been added! See the edit.

Comment: Why don't you delete your old answer, so that other users can see the solution, not history.

Answer (score 5):

#### Finding successive pairs

If you're willing to use a third party library and don't need parallelism, then [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) offers SQL-style window functions as follows

```java
System.out.println(
Seq.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
   .window()
   .filter(w -> w.lead().isPresent())
   .map(w -> tuple(w.value(), w.lead().get())) // alternatively, use your new Pair() class
   .toList()
);
```

Yielding

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

The `lead()` function accesses the next value in traversal order from the window.

#### Finding successive triples / quadruples / n-tuples

A question in the comments was asking for a more general solution, where not pairs but n-tuples (or possibly lists) should be collected. Here's thus an alternative approach:

```java
int n = 3;

System.out.println(
Seq.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
   .window(0, n - 1)
   .filter(w -> w.count() == n)
   .map(w -> w.window().toList())
   .toList()
);
```

Yielding a list of lists

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Without the `filter(w -> w.count() == n)`, the result would be

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ

Comment: Interesting. What if I need to group 3 or more elements? Use `w.lead().lead()`?

Comment: @RaulSantelices: `tuple(w.value(), w.lead(1), w.lead(2))` would be an option. I've updated my answer with a more generic solution for `length = n`

Comment: I understand correctly that `.window()` is not lazy operation which collects the whole input stream into some intermediate collection, then creates a new stream from it?

Comment: @TagirValeev: Yes, that's the current implementation. In the above case (no `Comparator` is used to reorder windows), then an optimisation like [this](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/issues/177) would be possible, and is likely to be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The operation is essentially stateful so not really what streams are meant to solve - see the "Stateless Behaviors" section in the [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> The best approach is to avoid stateful behavioral parameters to stream operations entirely

One solution here is to introduce state in your stream through an external counter, although it will only work with a sequential stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "c");
    AtomicReference<String> previous = new AtomicReference<>();
    List<Pair> collect = strings.map(n -> {
                            String p = previous.getAndSet(n);
                            return p == null ? null : new Pair(p, n);
                        })
                        .filter(p -> p != null)
                        .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}


static class Pair<T> {
    private T left, right;
    Pair(T left, T right) { this.left = left; this.right = right; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "{" + left + "," + right + '}'; }
}
```

Comment: The question asks to collect successive elements of an input stream, not merely to collect successive integers. An important clarification of terminology: `Stream` != "lambdas".

Comment: You could replace AtomicInteger by an AtomicReference. The alternative is to roll your own collector or use external libraries such as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30090528/829571

Comment: See my edit. Also I'm not sure I understand your comment on lambda != stream. The other answer that uses an anonymous class does essentially the same thing except that the state is held by the anonymous class instead of being external...

Comment: That works. The `StreamEx` library is also a good find and could be an answer in itself. My comment on "streams != lambdas" refers to you stating "The operation is essentially stateful so not really what lambdas are meant to solve." I think you meant to use the word "streams".

Comment: Oh I see - I've clarified that.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) (very powerful [reactive extension](http://reactivex.io/) library)

```
IntStream intStream  = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1);

Observable<List<Integer>> pairObservable = Observable.from(intStream::iterator).buffer(2,1);

pairObservable.take(10).forEach(b -> {
            b.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
            System.out.println();
        });
```

> The *buffer* [operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) transforms an Observable that
>   emits items into an Observable that emits buffered collections of
>   those items..

Comment: I used `Observable.zip(obs, obs.skip(1), pair->{...})` up until now! I didn't know `Observable.buffer` had a version with a step (and I'm used to the `zip` trick from python). +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use Flux:

```
Stream<String> someStream = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D");
Flux<String> someFlux = Flux.fromStream(someStream);

someFlux.zipWith(someFlux.skip(1))
    .map(t -> t.getT1().concat(t.getT2()))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The result would be:

```
AB
BC
CD
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a way of tricking the Stream.reduce to be able to neatly deal with pairs of values; there are a multitude of use cases that require this facility which does not appear *naturally* in JDK 8:

```
public static int ArithGeo(int[] arr) {
    //Geometric
    List<Integer> diffList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> divList = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(arr).reduce((left, right) -> {
        diffList.add(right-left);
        divList.add(right/left);
        return right;
    });
    //Arithmetic
    if(diffList.stream().distinct().count() == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    //Geometric
    if(divList.stream().distinct().count() == 1) {
        return 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The trick i use is the **return right;** statement.

Comment: I don't think `reduce` makes sufficient guarantees for this to work.

Comment: Would be interested to know more about the **sufficient guarantees**. Can you please elaborate? Maybe there is an alternative in Guava...but I am constrained and cannot use it.

Comment: Reduce works like a charm for paired filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions here seem a little complicated or depend on third-party libraries. This problem can be solved with an intermediate stream which collect pairs:

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> pairs(Stream<T> stream) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        T first = iterator.next();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            return Stream.iterate(
                List.of(first, iterator.next()),
                prev -> iterator.hasNext() ? List.of(prev.get(1), iterator.next()) : null)
                .takeWhile(prev -> prev != null);
        }
    }
    return Stream.empty();
}
```

Examples:

```
pairs(Stream.of()).toList();      // []
pairs(Stream.of(1)).toList();     // []
pairs(Stream.of(1,2)).toList();   // [[1, 2]]
pairs(Stream.of(1,2,3)).toList(); // [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
pairs(Stream.of("a","b","c","d")).toList();  // [[a, b], [b, c], [c, d]]
```

In this solution, `Stream.iterate`is using an accumulator in much the same way as `reduce`, except it creates an intermediate stream rather than being a terminal operation. So laziness and infinite streams are supported.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would write my custom IntFunction which keeps track of the last int passed and use that to map the original IntStream.

```
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PairFunction implements IntFunction<PairFunction.Pair> {

  public static class Pair {

    private final int first;
    private final int second;

    public Pair(int first, int second) {
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "[" + first + "|" + second + "]";
    }
  }

  private int last;
  private boolean first = true;

  @Override
  public Pair apply(int value) {
    Pair pair = !first ? new Pair(last, value) : null;
    last = value;
    first = false;
    return pair;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    final PairFunction pairFunction = new PairFunction();
    intStream.mapToObj(pairFunction)
        .filter(p -> p != null) // filter out the null
        .forEach(System.out::println); // display each Pair

  }

}
```

Comment: Problem with this is it throws statelessness out the window.

Comment: @Rob and what's the problem with that?

Comment: One of the main points of lambda is to not have mutable state so that the internal integrators can parallelism the work.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, you are right, but the given example stream defies parallelism anyway as each item (except the first and last ones) is used as a first and a second item of some pair.

Comment: @jpvee yeah I figured that's what you were thinking. I wonder though if there is not a way to do this with some other mapper. In essence all you'd need would be the equivalent of making the loop incrementer go by twos then have the functor take 2 arguments. That must be possible.

Comment: Wait that would not work because the result pairs overlap. Of course you could have the non overlapping pairs made then make the overlapping ones from the created ones. But that would be mutlipass. Would be interesting to see how that would perform.

Comment: @Rob Prematurely optimize much? I don't get the whole emphasis on parallelism with streams. Parallelism is for special situations only. Besides, you can just put `.parallel()` *after* the `map(byPairs)`.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be to use [zip](http://download.java.net/lambda/b95/docs/api/java/util/stream/Streams.html#zip%28java.util.stream.Stream,%20java.util.stream.Stream,%20java.util.function.BiFunction%29). Something like:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
Stream<Pair> pairStream = Streams.zip(input.stream(),
                                      input.stream().substream(1),
                                      (a, b) -> new Pair(a, b)
);
```

This is pretty concise and elegant, however it uses a list as an input. An infinite stream source cannot be processed this way.

Another (lot more troublesome) issue is that zip together with the entire Streams class has been lately removed from the API. The above code only works with [b95](http://download.java.net/lambda/b95/) or older releases. So with the latest JDK I would say there is no elegant FP style solution and right now we can just hope that in some way zip will be reintroduced to the API.

Comment: Indeed, `zip` was removed. I don't remember all of what was on the `Streams` class, but some things have migrated to be static methods on the `Stream` interface, and there are also `StreamSupport` and `Stream.Builder` classes.

Comment: That's right. Some other methods like concat or iterate has been moved and became default methods in Stream. Sadly zip was just removed from the API. I understand the reasons behind this choice (e.g. lack of Tuples) but still it was a nice feature.

Comment: @gadget What do tuples have to do with `zip`? Whatever pedantic reason might be invented does not justify killing `zip`.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky In most cases zip is used to produce a collection of Pairs/Tuples as an output. They [argued](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-June/001902.html) that if they kept zip people would ask for Tuples as part of the JDK as well. I would have never removed an existing feature though.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating successive differences in the time (x-values) of a time-series, I use the `stream`'s `collect(...)` method:

```
final List< Long > intervals = timeSeries.data().stream()
                    .map( TimeSeries.Datum::x )
                    .collect( DifferenceCollector::new, DifferenceCollector::accept, DifferenceCollector::combine )
                    .intervals();
```

Where the DifferenceCollector is something like this:

```
public class DifferenceCollector implements LongConsumer
{
    private final List< Long > intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    private Long lastTime;

    @Override
    public void accept( final long time )
    {
        if( Objects.isNull( lastTime ) )
        {
            lastTime = time;
        }
        else
        {
            intervals.add( time - lastTime );
            lastTime = time;
        }
    }

    public void combine( final DifferenceCollector other )
    {
        intervals.addAll( other.intervals );
        lastTime = other.lastTime;
    }

    public List< Long > intervals()
    {
        return intervals;
    }
}
```

You could probably modify this to suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting problem. Is my *hybrid* attempt below any good?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    Iterator<Integer> first = list.iterator();
    first.next();
    if (first.hasNext())
        list.stream()
        .skip(1)
        .map(v -> new Pair(first.next(), v))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I believe it does not lend itself to parallel processing, and hence may be disqualified.

Comment: The question didn't ask for parallel processing, but it did assume that we only have a `Stream`, not a `List`. Of course, we can pry an iterator from a Stream as well, so this might be a valid solution. Nevertheless, it's an original approach.

Answer (score -1):

As others have observed, there is, due to the nature of the problem, some statefulness required.

I was faced with a similar problem, in which I wanted what was essentially the Oracle SQL function LEAD. My attempt to implement that is below.

```
/**
 * Stream that pairs each element in the stream with the next subsequent element.
 * The final pair will have only the first item, the second will be null.
 */
<T> Spliterator<Pair<T>> lead(final Stream<T> stream)
{
    final Iterator<T> input = stream.sequential().iterator();

    final Iterable<Pair<T>> iterable = () ->
    {
        return new Iterator<Pair<T>>()
        {
            Optional<T> current = getOptionalNext(input);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return current.isPresent();
            }

            @Override
            public Pair<T> next()
            {
                Optional<T> next = getOptionalNext(input);
                final Pair<T> pair = next.isPresent()
                    ? new Pair(current.get(), next.get())
                    : new Pair(current.get(), null);
                current = next;

                return pair;
            }
        };
    };

    return iterable.spliterator();
}

private <T> Optional<T> getOptionalNext(final Iterator<T> iterator)
{
    return iterator.hasNext()
        ? Optional.of(iterator.next())
        : Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by using a bounded queue to store elements which flows through the stream (which is basing on the idea which I described in detail here: [Is it possible to get next element in the Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650157/is-it-possible-to-get-next-element-in-the-stream/40450777#40450777))

Belows example first defines instance of BoundedQueue class which will store elements going through the stream (if you don't like idea of extending the LinkedList, refer to link mentioned above for alternative and more generic approach). Later you just combine two subsequent elements into instance of Pair:

```
public class TwoSubsequentElems {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>(asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4));

    class BoundedQueue<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
      public BoundedQueue<T> save(T curElem) {
        if (size() == 2) { // we need to know only two subsequent elements
          pollLast(); // remove last to keep only requested number of elements
        }

        offerFirst(curElem);

        return this;
      }

      public T getPrevious() {
        return (size() < 2) ? null : getLast();
      }

      public T getCurrent() {
        return (size() == 0) ? null : getFirst();
      }
    }

    BoundedQueue<Integer> streamHistory = new BoundedQueue<Integer>();

    final List<Pair<Integer>> answer = input.stream()
      .map(i -> streamHistory.save(i))
      .filter(e -> e.getPrevious() != null)
      .map(e -> new Pair<Integer>(e.getPrevious(), e.getCurrent()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    answer.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I agree with @aepurniet
but instead map you have to use mapToObj

```
range(0, 100).mapToObj((i) -> new Pair(i, i+1)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Right. But this simply collects pairs of integers, not pairs of elements of a stream (of any type).

Comment: It doesn't work for  collection eg. fibonacci 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13...

Answer (score -6):

Run a `for` loop that runs from 0 to `length-1` of your stream

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < stream.length-1 ; i++)
{
    Pair pair = new Pair(stream[i], stream[i+1]);
    // then add your pair to an array
}
```

Comment: and where is the lambda part of the solution?

Comment: It is not the case when stream is infinite

Comment: @Olimpiu - Where did you get a lambda was a requirement? I read the question twice to make sure I was not missing it. I also checked history of edits. And the question is not tagged with it.

Comment: It should be deleted