# How to partition a collection into arbitrary sized partition

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java 8 Lambda expressions and streams to parse some logs.  I have one giant log file that has run after run.  I want to split it into separate collections, one for each run.  I do not know how many runs the log has in advanced.  And to exercise my very weak lambda expressions muscles I'd like to do it in one pass through the list.

Here is my current implementation:

```
    List<String> lines = readLines(fileDirectory);

    Pattern runStartPattern = Pattern.compile("INFO: \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d: Starting");

    LinkedList<List<String>> testRuns = new LinkedList<>();

    List<String> currentTestRun = new LinkedList<>(); // In case log starts in middle of run
    testRuns.add(currentTestRun);

    for(String line:lines){
        if(runStartPattern.matcher(line).find()){
            currentTestRun = new ArrayList<>();
            testRuns.add(currentTestRun);
        }
        currentTestRun.add(line);
    }
    if(testRuns.getFirst().size()==0){ // In case log starts at a run
        testRuns.removeFirst();
    }
```

Basically something like TomekRekawek's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/java-8-collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream) but with an unknown partition size to begin with.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You have described what you want to do, not the difficulty you are having trying to do it.

Comment: I don't see a way to do this same thing with a stream.  I don't know how in a stream to mark the next element as needing to create a new `List<String>`

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095967/splitting-list-into-sublists-along-elements/29096777#29096777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard way to easily achieve this in Stream API, but my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has a [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) method which can solve this pretty easily:

```
List<List<String>> testLines = StreamEx.of(lines)
        .groupRuns((a, b) -> !runStartPattern.matcher(b).find())
        .toList();
```

It groups the input elements based on some predicate which is applied to the pair of adjacent elements. Here we don't want to group the lines if the second line matches the `runStartPattern`. This works correctly regardless of whether the log starts in the middle of run or not. Also this feature works nice with parallel streams as well.

Comment: Btw, did you add it to your API in response to my question?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas, nope, I've just found your question. The groupRuns feature is useful in [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31026610/4856258) places [as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31406013/4856258). It's part of the partial reduction family along with `collapse`, `runLengths` and `intervalMap` methods which combine several adjacent elements into one and internally use the same mechanism.