# Combining sub sets to larger sets if they share common value

Tags: java, set, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create a method that would return largest set of cards which has neighbors. For example if I have `list<RANK> rankList = [FIVE, QUEEN, KING, ACE, TEN]` it would return `[KING, ACE, QUEEN]`. I haven't fully implemented it, but I got that part with splits one set in multiple smaller sets.

```
private boolean isStraight(List<Card> cards) {
        Set<RANK> rankList = cards.stream()
            .map(Card::getRank)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());


        List<Set<RANK>> subSets = new ArrayList<>();

        for(RANK rank : rankList) {
            int currRankValue = rank.getValue();
            RANK prevRank = RANK.getRank(currRankValue - 1);
            RANK nextRank = RANK.getRank(currRankValue + 1);

            if(!subSets.stream().anyMatch(set -> set.contains(rank))) {
                Set<RANK> newSet = new HashSet<>();
                newSet.add(rank);
                subSets.add(newSet);
            }

            subSets.stream()
                .filter(set -> (set.contains(prevRank) || set.contains(nextRank)))
                .forEach( set -> set.add(rank));
        }

        System.out.print(subSets);
        return false;
    }
```

**Card.java**:

```
 public static enum RANK {
        NONE(0),
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5),
        SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
        TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13), ACE(14);

        private final int value;

        private RANK(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static RANK getRank(int value) {
            for(RANK r : RANK.values() ) {
                if (r.getValue() == value)
                    return r;
            }
            return NONE;
        }
    }
```

And before I check if there is 5 or more cards that could make a straight I have combine sub sets which has at least one common value. How can I do it? I'cant think of anything that wouldn't involve many loops.

**EDITED**

Added whole **Card.java**:

```
ppackage deck;

public class Card implements Comparable {

    public static enum SUIT {
        SPADES,
        HEARTS,
        CLUBS,
        DIAMONDS
    }

    public static enum RANK {
        NONE(0),
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5),
        SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
        TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13), ACE(14);

        private final int value;

        private RANK(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static RANK getRank(int value) {
            for(RANK r : RANK.values() ) {
                if (r.getValue() == value)
                    return r;
            }
            return NONE;
        }
    }

    private final RANK rank;
    private final SUIT suit;

    public Card(RANK rank, SUIT suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public RANK getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public SUIT getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
            "rank=" + rank +
            ", suit=" + suit +
            '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object that) {
        return this.rank.getValue() - ((Card) that).rank.getValue();
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

Added solution with loops:
adding this before return in the method.

```
for(int index = 0; index < subSets.size(); index++) {
           for(int index2 = 1; index2 < subSets.size(); index2++) {
               if(!Collections.disjoint(subSets.get(index), subSets.get(index2)) && index != index2) {
                    subSets.get(index).addAll(subSets.remove(index2));
                    index2--;
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: I saw that you spelled which as with twice. (Not related to your question). Can you show the card class?

Comment: So when are two cards equal?

Comment: I'm thinking I could use something similiar to `.reduce()` method, which would do calculation 1 to everyone after it, not 1 to next.

Comment: And how does the JVM know that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76077/discussion-between-artrs-and-bot).

Comment: `compareTo` is used for sorting. `equals` is used for checking equality. Does your code do what it is supposed to even before you move to implementing the remaining parts?

Comment: Yes everything works fine. At one point I had some issues when debugging mode return different results then production mode.

Comment: Also I'm mapping `getRank()` result with is enum and `distinct()` is removing duplicates with has same rank value.

Comment: Like I said, `compareTo` is not used for checking equality. The assumptions based on which you wrote your program are wrong so I doubt it does what is supposed to. You have not overriden `equals` in the `Card` class.

Comment: It's not looking at `Card` objects, but at`RANK` enums

Comment: Okay you are right. That's my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm focusing on the aspect of the problem relating to the "largest set of cards which has neighbors." If the list of card rank values is sorted, this turns into the problem of segmenting the list runs and then picking the longest run(s) from those segments.

Astute readers will note the similarity to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095967/splitting-list-into-sublists-along-elements). I'll use a technique similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29111023/1441122) to that question.

First, let's start off with an input list containing as in the OP's example. The following technique should work for any input, though.

```
    List<Rank> rankList = [FIVE, QUEEN, KING, ACE, TEN];
```

Let's sort and make this list have unique elements:

```
    List<Rank> sorted = rankList.stream()
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .collect(toList());
```

> [FIVE, TEN, QUEEN, KING, ACE]

Now let's compute the location where the list should be split to separate runs of consecutive rank values. This occurs at locations where values adjacent to each other in the list are not consecutive rank values. We do this by indexing the list (starting from 1) and filtering the indexes by examining adjacent values from the list:

```
    List<Integer> splits = IntStream.range(1, sorted.size())
        .filter(i -> sorted.get(i).ordinal() != sorted.get(i-1).ordinal() + 1)
        .boxed()
        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

> [1, 2]

These are the locations *between* the runs. This is almost enough information to create sublists, but it omits the index for the start of the first sublist and for the end of the last sublist. To add these, we just add *0* at the front and *size* at the end:

```
    splits.add(0, 0);
    splits.add(list.size());
```

> [0, 1, 2, 5]

Now we can use each pair of indexes to generate the sublists containing each run:

```
    List<List<Rank>> runs = IntStream.range(1, splits.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(splits.get(i-1), splits.get(i)))
        .collect(toList());
```

> [[FIVE], [TEN], [QUEEN, KING, ACE]]

We can find the longest run and then print out the runs that match its length:

```
    int longest = runs.stream()
        .mapToInt(list -> list.size())
        .max()
        .getAsInt();
    runs.stream()
        .filter(list -> list.size() == longest)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> [QUEEN, KING, ACE]

Putting it all together, we have:

```
static void split(List<Rank> rankList) {
    List<Rank> sorted = rankList.stream()
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .collect(toList());

    List<Integer> splits = IntStream.range(1, sorted.size())
        .filter(i -> sorted.get(i).ordinal() != sorted.get(i-1).ordinal() + 1)
        .boxed()
        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    splits.add(0, 0);
    splits.add(sorted.size());

    List<List<Rank>> runs = IntStream.range(1, splits.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> sorted.subList(splits.get(i-1), splits.get(i)))
        .collect(toList());

    int longest = runs.stream()
        .mapToInt(list -> list.size())
        .max()
        .getAsInt();

    runs.stream()
        .filter(list -> list.size() == longest)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Readable, small steps. Nice details.

Comment: If you are interested in only one largest run, you may use `runs.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))`…

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that a “straight” consists of five adjacent `RANK`s, we should not think too complicated but just test whether we find such a range:

```
boolean isStraight(List<Card> cards) {
    BitSet set=cards.stream().map(Card::getRank).mapToInt(Card.RANK::ordinal)
        .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
    for(int s=set.nextSetBit(0), e; s>=0; s=set.nextSetBit(e)) {
        e=set.nextClearBit(s);
        if(e-s >= 5) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code is not bound to a specific *hand* size and could be easily adapted to other *straight* sizes.

Dealing with `ordinal()` and `BitSet`s might look a bit low-level, and I really wished there was a solution using `EnumSet` or `EnumMap` as simple as that, however, these higher level classes are not that helpful here (they don’t even implement `SortedSet`/`SortedMap`)…

---

Note that this method returns a `boolean` as the code in your question. So it doesn’t care what actual cards make up the straight. Afaik, in most Poker variants it indeed doesn’t matter.

However, taking your question’s introduction literally, getting the “largest set of cards which has neighbors” can be done as follows:

```
Set<Card> largestStraightCandidate(List<Card> cards) {
    BitSet set=cards.stream().map(Card::getRank).mapToInt(Card.RANK::ordinal)
        .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
    int min=0, max=0;
    for(int s=set.nextSetBit(0), e; s>=0; s=set.nextSetBit(e)) {
        e=set.nextClearBit(s);
        if(e-s >= max-min) {
            min=s;
            max=e;
        }
    }
    if(max==min) return Collections.emptySet();// cards was empty
    Card.RANK[] all=Card.RANK.values();
    EnumSet<Card.RANK> rankSet=EnumSet.range(all[min], all[max-1]);
    return cards.stream().filter(card-> rankSet.contains(card.getRank()))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

The difference is that we now remember the largest range instead of returning once we found a sufficiently large one. Then, we reconstitute the cards by filtering the original card list for all cards within that range.

This implies that

- for multiple largest set, the set with the higher ranks will be returned as due to the loop over the `BitSet`, i.e. the order within the list doesn’t matter
- if multiple cards of the same `RANK` within the range exists, all of them are included in the `Set` of `Card`s; don’t use its size to decide about the straight’s size, you have to convert to a `Set` of `RANK`s first, or well, if you look closely at the code, you see that the `Set` of `RANK`s already exists *before* the `Set` of `Card`s is built…

Answer (score 2):

(I am still having troubles with the coding style of the java functional API.) I would use a distinct sorted stream, and use Lists to make sub-lists.
The distinct list is split into sub-lists of consecutive ranks. I would like to see a better solution with flatMap, reduce or whatever.

```
static boolean isStraight(List<Card> cards) {
    List<List<Rank>> rankList = cards.stream()
            .map(Card::getRank)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Rank::getValue))
            .distinct()
            .collect(LinkedList::new,
                    (list, rank) -> {
                        boolean startNextList = false;
                        if (list.isEmpty()) {
                            startNextList = true;
                        } else {
                            List<Rank> priorRanks = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                            if (priorRanks.get(priorRanks.size() - 1).getValue()
                                       < rank.getValue() - 1) {
                                startNextList = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (startNextList) {
                            List<Rank> priorRanks = new LinkedList<>();
                            list.add(priorRanks);
                        }
                        List<Rank> priorRanks = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                        priorRanks.add(rank);
                    },
                    (list1, list2) -> {
                        list1.addAll(list2);
                    });
```

A dump:

```
    rankList.stream().forEach((list) -> {
        System.out.printf("# %d - ", list.size());
        list.stream().forEach((r) -> System.out.printf("%s, ", r));
        System.out.println();
    });
    ...
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29839295/1441122). You might find it familiar. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given that there are so few possible straights, have you considered a simpler approach of just precomputing them all?

```
// using .ordinal() instead of .value to keep it short.  
// Shouldn't be too hard to change it to use values
final Set<EnumSet<RANK>> STRAIGHTS = EnumSet.range(TWO, TEN).stream()
        .map(rank -> EnumSet.range(rank, RANK.values()[rank.ordinal() + 4]))
        .collect(toSet());
```

and then

```
boolean isStraight(List<Card> cards) {
    EnumSet<RANK> ranks = cards.stream()
        .map(Card::getRank)
        .collect(toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(RANK.class)));

    return STRAIGHTS.contains(ranks);
}
```