# Divide a set into smaller sets - Java

Tags: java, set, guava

I have a set, which I would like to divide into smaller sets of size x. Guava has something similar for lists - [Lists.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29). But I couldn't find anything related to Sets. Are there any libraries which can help me in doing this? If not, what's the best way to break a set into smaller sets?

Edit: Currently, I'm doing it as follows:

```
int x = 10;
Set<String> stringSet = createHashSet();
for (List<String> partition : Iterables.partition(stringSet, x) {
    doSomething(new HashSet<>(partition));
}
```

I'm using this [Iterables.partition](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html). There should be better ways to do it, which doesn't involve converting set to a list, and then back to a set.

Comment: What is your partitioning logic?

Comment: `Set` is by definition unordered so the partitioning logic which exists in Guava for `List` will not apply. You need to create something yourself for this, depending on the `Set` implementation class (`hash`, `tree`, etc..)

Comment: Java 8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095967/splitting-list-into-sublists-along-elements

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I don't need any special partitioning logic.

Comment: @Kon - I have a HashSet.  I just want to break it into smaller sets and process those in batches.

Comment: What are those smaller sets made of? What do they contain? Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> input = /*defined elsewhere*/;
int x = 10;

List<Set<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> currSet = null;
for (Integer value : input) {
    if (currSet == null || currSet.size() == x)
        output.add(currSet = new HashSet<>());
    currSet.add(value);
}
```

Result is, for all intends and purposes, random. It is undefined which elements of the input set going into which set of the output, and within an output set, the values will be in arbitrary order.