# Count occurrence of ArrayList broken into groups

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I'm trying to figure out how to count the occurrence of an element in an `ArrayList` that's being broken up by dashes `---`.

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
animals.add("dog");
animals.add("cat");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("---");
animals.add("cat");
animals.add("dog");
animals.add("dog");
animals.add("---");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("dog");
```

So my `ArrayList` looks like this:

```
animals = {"dog", "cat", "bat", "bat", "---", "cat", "dog", "dog", "---", "bat", "bat", "dog"}
```

And I want my output to (alphabetically) look like this:

```
bat: 2
cat: 1
dog: 1
---
cat: 1
dog: 2
---
bat: 2
dog: 1
```

Before I had the dashes, I was getting the occurrence by using this

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(animals, "bat");
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: There is no built in function for that. You have to iterate over every single entry and start re-counting after every dash.

Comment: Your question is not related to Android. Do not tag improperly to gain viability.

Comment: @MuratK. Yea, that's what I'm thinking. I'm debating on adding each element into another arraylist until I hit the dashes and then calling the frequency function that way. Either that or just do everything manually

Comment: You don't have to do that. You can use the `List::subList` method. But a manual scan would be more efficient, I believe, because you won't need to look for each and every value again and again.

Comment: [Splitting List into sublists along elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095967/splitting-list-into-sublists-along-elements) has solutions for splitting into groups which you can then calculate the frequencies from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mostly depends on how do you plan to use the frequency for each value. If the objective is just to print it, then following:

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> freq = new TreeMap<>(); // to sort keys alphabetically
for (String animal : animals) {
  if (animal.equals("---")) {
    System.out.println(freq);
    freq.clear();
  } else {
    freq.merge(animal, 1, Integer::sum);
  }
}
System.out.println(freq);
```

will output:

```
{bat=2, cat=1, dog=1}
{cat=1, dog=2}
{bat=2, dog=1}
```

Comment: instead of `freq.compute(animal, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);` I would recommend `freq.merge(animal, 1, Integer::sum)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java8 you can construct something truly horrific, extracting the index range for each sub-list and collecting references to the elements within each range into separate lists:

```
int[] indexes = 
  Stream.of(IntStream.of(-1), IntStream.range(0, animals.size())
  .filter(i -> animals.get(i).equals("---")), IntStream.of(animals.size()))
  .flatMapToInt(s -> s).toArray();
List<List<String>> subSets = 
  IntStream.range(0, indexes.length - 1)
           .mapToObj(i -> animals.subList(indexes[i] + 1, indexes[i + 1]))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (List l : subSets) {
    int uiBats = Collections.frequency(l, "bat");
    ...
```

or alternatively iterate over the list like a normal person:

```
for(String value : animals){
  LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();
  if(value.equals("---")) {
     values.add(temp);
     temp = new LinkedList<String>();
  }else{
     temp.add(value);
  }
}
for(LinkedList<String> list : values){
  System.out.println("Frequency in " + list + " is " + Collections.frequency(list,     "bat"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Multiset` from guava:

```
    final Multiset<String> multiset = TreeMultiset.create();
    for (final String animal : animals)
    {
        if (!animal.equals("---"))
        {
            multiset.add(animal);
        } else
        {
            print(multiset);
            multiset.clear();
        }
    }
    print(multiset);
}

private static void print(final Multiset<String> multiset)
{
    multiset.entrySet().forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getElement() + " = " + v.getCount()));

    System.out.println("---");
}
```

Result:

```
bat = 2
cat = 1
dog = 1
---
cat = 1
dog = 2
---
bat = 2
dog = 1
---
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to use Collections.frequency(..), then you can create a

```
List<List<String>> values = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
```

then iterate over the animals list and add to lists to values

```
for(String value : animals){
  LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();
  if(value.equals("---")) {
     values.add(temp);
     temp = new LinkedList<String>();
  }else{
     temp.add(value);
  }
}
for(LinkedList<String> list : values){
  System.out.println("Frequency in " + list + " is " + Collections.frequency(list, "bat"));
}
```

I have no IDE to test it, but that should work :)

Good luck!