# Create stream of streams from one long stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to split a single `Stream` into a `Stream` of `Streams` based on the contents of the `Streams`. The resulting the `Stream` should contain part of the original streams' data.

My real application is more complex (it is grouping log lines that are within a list of time intervals), but my problem is how to handle the streams, so here I ask about a simplified example.

## Example problem

I want to be able split a `Stream<Integer>` into a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>` based on the same number being repeated, only leaving the streams with odd numbers.

For example the following stream containing:

`{1,1,1,2,2,2,3,6,7,7,1,1}`

Would need to result in a stream of streams containing:

`{{1,1,1},{3},{7,7},{1,1}}`

Leaving out the even numbers I can do by starting (or ending) with a filter:

```
Stream<Integer> input = ...;
Straem<Stream<Integer>> output = input.filter(this::isOdd).someOtherOperation();
```

This is undesired as it would mean evaluating each input value twice, this is acceptable but I would prefer avoiding this.

## Ideas for solutions

My current solution does this iterating over the contents of the stream and creating a `List<List<Integer>>` and converting that to a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`. However this means the full result is kept in memory (which is undesired for my application).

I also think I would be able to pull this of by writing my own `Iterator` that reads from the stream, but I am not sure how this would work.

## Question

How can I convert a `Stream` into a `Stream` of `Streams` based on the contents of the original `Stream`, without storing the full result in as a `List` of `Lists` first.

Comment: The big question is why do you want that? It looks like an XY problem to me. After all, a `Stream` is useful only for performing a certain terminal operation and while solutions trying to provide you with new `Stream`s are rather complicated, they are unnecessary as the actual task is “how do I apply terminal operation *X* to chunks of the `Stream`” which can be best solved when knowing what *X* is.

Comment: @Holger as said in the question, the reason for asking, is a problem where I am going through large amounts of logs and am interested in selections of those, preferably without storing too much in memory, streams seam to be a good way to achieve this because they only calculate something when it is used. I chose to ask the question about a more simple problem to make sure the answers were about streams, which is what I want to learn more about.

Comment: So when you don’t use it, even `Stream`s are a waste of memory. The reason why grouping solutions in the answers end up creating collections is that your question lacks an alternative. Once you have a real computation/analytic task to solve, you may combine that operation with the grouping operation into one fused terminal operation and apply it on the original `Stream`. There is no need for neither, `List` of `List` nor `Stream` of `Stream`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to implement your own [aggregating spliterator](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codepoetics/protonpack/AggregatingSpliterator.java) to do this. There's already something similar in the [proton-pack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) library (the first link redirects to the one implemented in proton-pack).

Note that you get a `Stream<List<Integer>>` (you may try to modify the implementation to have a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>` directly, but you always need to buffer a small amount elements; depending on the window's size; to test whether you should create a new window or not). So for example:

```
StreamUtils.aggregate(Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1), 
                      Objects::equals)
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3]
[6]
[7, 7]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: Again, having stream of lists means that these lists with all the elements are stored in the memory which is undesired.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak As I understand it, each list is built when the pipeline requires a next piece of data (with the `tryAdvance` method). When it will be done the `currentSlide` list is reinitialized with a new reference (`currentSlide = new ArrayList<>();`) so the previous one will be eligible for GC I guess, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure with that (if someone can approve or disapprove this, that would help).

Comment: Using a Stream<List<Integer>> where each list is created only when it is requested is definitely an improvement over my current implementation. Which is indeed what the protonpack does.

Comment: @Thirler I tried to do one that returns a `Stream<Stream<Integer>>` directly.  Take it at your own risk: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/f55adaf22985904d35d9  ;)

Comment: @AlexisC., the `Stream.Builder` solution does not differ much from protonpack version: it still stores the whole slide inside the `SpinedBuffer`. For this particular task you may just count the number of elements in the group, then use `Stream.generate(() -> e).limit(n)`.

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes this is what I said in parenthesis in my answer. Your suggestion is a better improvement (or `IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> e)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. It has [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) which does the job:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1);
Stream<Stream<Integer>> streams = StreamEx.of(input).filter(this::isOdd)
    .groupRuns(Integer::equals)
    .map(List::stream);
```

Usage example:

```
streams.map(s -> StreamEx.of(s).joining(",")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1,1,1
3
7,7
1,1
```

Similar to protonpack library there's a custom spliterator inside, but using StreamEx you can take advantage of parallel processing (the protonpack does not split at all).

In sequential processing at most one intermediate list resides in memory at a time (others are eligible for GC). If you still worry about memory consumption (for example, you have very long groups), there is an alternative way to solve this task since the StreamEx 0.3.3:

```
Stream<Stream<Integer>> streams = StreamEx.of(input).filter(this::isOdd)
        .runLengths()
        .mapKeyValue(StreamEx::constant);
```

The [`runLengths`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/) method returns the stream of entries where key is the element and value is the number of adjacent repeating elements. After that `StreamEx.constant` is used which is shortcut for `Stream.generate(() -> value).limit(length)`. So you will have a constant intermediate memory consumption even for very long groups. Of course this version is also parallel-friendly.

**Update:** StreamEx 0.3.3 is released, thus the second solution is now eligible as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it is not doable, at least not in a nice way. Even if you map the elements into streams and reduce them, these internal streams will have to know what elements they contain so they will have to store something.

The simplest solution is to just use `groupingBy` however it will store all results in the map:

```
List<Integer> input = asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = input.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i));
Stream<Stream<Integer>> streamOfStreams = grouped.values().stream().map(list -> list.stream());
```

You could try using `reduce` operation but it would require you to implement your own Stream of Streams in which you would have to store what elements every stream contains anyway. Not to mention that it would be a lot of effort to implement it.

The best solution I can think of in your case would be to iterate over the list twice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> input = asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1);

    input.stream().distinct().filter(i -> isOdd(i)).forEach(i -> {
        List<Integer> subList = input.stream().filter(j -> Objects.equals(j, i)).collect(toList());
        System.out.println(subList); // do something with the stream instead of collecting to list
    });
}

private static boolean isOdd(Integer i) {
    return (i & 1) == 1;
}
```

Note however that it has `O(n^2)` time complexity.

**EDIT:**

This solution will only have local groups of elements. It stores only the current local group.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> input = Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1);

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = input.iterator();
    int first;
    int second = iterator.next();

    List<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    buffer.add(second);

    do {
        first = second;
        second = iterator.next();

        if (Objects.equals(first, second)) {
            buffer.add(second);
        } else {
            doSomethingWithTheGroup(buffer);
            buffer = new ArrayList<>(); // let GC remove the previous buffer
            buffer.add(second);
        }
    } while (iterator.hasNext());
    doSomethingWithTheGroup(buffer);
}

private static void doSomethingWithTheGroup(List<Integer> buffer) {
    System.out.println(buffer);
}

private static boolean isOdd(Integer i) {
    return (i & 1) == 1;
}
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3]
[6]
[7, 7]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: In my problem i want to create local groups. Using `groupBy`, for example, creates a single group of `1` instead of 2 groups.

Comment: Good point. How about just getting elements from the stream and comparing them manually? You can take iterator from the stream and call next on it - having the iterator you can do a classical `while(iterator.hasNext())` loop.

Comment: That is indeed my current solution, but do the full iteration over the input before returning the stream (based on internal lists). Which works but stores all results in memory.

Comment: I have added edited my answer and added a solution which only stores a local group in the memory (which I think you cannot avoid anyway).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good improvement over my current solution without using streams.

Comment: Why are you calling `input.stream().iterator()` instead of just `input.iterator()`? Just to have the `Stream` API involved somehow?

Comment: Beause in the user's case the input is a stream, not a list. I have used a list only for the setup to do the actual code. Anyway, I have changed it so this intention is better reflected now ;) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Like @Jaroslaw, I also used Map to hold the different Streams.  However, it **is** doable that the map will hold Streams that are built from the input and are not collected upfront.  Using `Stream.concat` and `Stream.of` you can add one element to a stream:

```
    Map<Integer, Stream<Integer>> streamMap = new HashMap<>();

    int[] arr = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,6,7,7,1,1};
    Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(this::isOdd)
    .forEach(i -> {
        Stream<Integer> st = streamMap.get(i);
        if (st == null)  st = Stream.of(i);
        else st = Stream.concat(st, Stream.of(i));
        streamMap.put(i, st);
    });

    streamMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.print(e.getKey() + "={");
        e.getValue().forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println("}");
    });
```

Output:

```
1={11111}
3={3}
7={77}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to just `grouping by` and storing everything in the list. `Stream.of` just stores the value that you passed in so your map will be using `O(n)` memory, which is exactly what @Thirler want to avoid.

Comment: `Stream.of` loads one element.  with my solution, inside the `forEach` you have access to the Map and all Streams as they get populated (=as the original stream is consumed).  With your solution, the Map is accessiable once the original stream is exhausted and everything got collected

Comment: True, but once you use entire stream your map will contain all the elements from this stream. Before refering to my solution, I would advise you to read my answer entirely, because it contains two solutions...

Comment: IMO, Your second solution does not answer the OP, as it does not give stream of streams. It gives option to load entire sub-stream one at a time

Comment: Note that this does not produce the same result as my example. Also this stores the full result in the map before printing it. The first forEach goes over the full input and stores the results, which is very much alike just storing a list of lists.

Comment: The print section is optional (its there just for debug), and can easily be moved inside the forEach method.  Like I said before, the heart of the solution is the forEach and the Stream.concat and Stream.of methods