# How to create a sublist from list using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of String containing RED and GREEN values

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("RED", "RED", "GREEN", "RED", "RED","GREEN", "GREEN");
```

I wanted to create a list containing sublists like the following but also maintain the same order

```
List<List<String>>=...{
    {"RED", "RED"},
    {"GREEN"},
    {"RED","RED"},
    {"GREEN", "GREEN"}
}
```

How can I go this using Java 8?

Comment: Did you even try it, using a for loop? Or do you need it fancy?

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021784/create-stream-of-streams-from-one-long-stream. It isn't straight-forward with stream API...