# Mapping Over an Ordered List in java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

In the streaming library included with Java 8, we're provided with the [forEachOrdered API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) whose documentation is reproduced here

> void forEachOrdered(Consumer action)
>
> Performs an action for each element of this stream.
>
> **This is a terminal operation.**
>
> This operation processes the elements one at a time, **in encounter order if one exists**. **Performing the action for one element happens-before performing the action for subsequent elements**, but for any given element, the action may be performed in whatever thread the library chooses.

Do we have any guarantees in terms of ordering from the [map API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)?

For example, I have the following in code

```
private final BazUtils bazUtils;

public List<Foo> getFoos(List<Bar> bars) {
    AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger(1);
    return bars.stream()
        .map(bar -> bazUtils.getFoo(bar, idx.getAndAdd(1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Will the order of `bars` be respected in processing?

Comment: I have difficulties to understand what you mean with your “function that takes an element and it's position in a list” as the function passed to `Stream.map` will receive only one argument and the stream doesn’t provide you a position. Besides that, it seems you are mixing up *processing* order and *encounter* order. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/2711488) help a bit (see also the  Stuart Marks’ comment there).

Comment: Holger, I can a provide function to map() which takes one argument but returns the call to another function that depends on multiple arguments.  For example, {idx; map(x -> foo(x, idx));}.

Comment: sure, but that `idx` is completely unrelated to `x` and its position.

Comment: And if `idx` is a heap variable that you are planning to modify, then the answer is **no**, there is no guaranty regarding *processing* order for parallel streams, the function may even get evaluated concurrently. You will likely run into race conditions when modifying the variable from within the mapping function. It’s the *encounter* order which will be maintained for the effective final result, if none of the intermediate steps nor the terminal action clear the ordered property of the stream.

Comment: Hi Holger, I've added details to my example in the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness), sections “Stateless behaviors” and “Side-effects”:

> …If the behavioral parameters do have side-effects, unless explicitly stated, there are no guarantees as to the [visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) of those side-effects to other threads, nor are there any guarantees that different operations on the "same" element within the same stream pipeline are executed in the same thread. Further, the ordering of those effects may be surprising. Even when a pipeline is constrained to produce a *result* that is consistent with the encounter order of the stream source (for example, `IntStream.range(0,5).parallel().map(x -> x*2).toArray()` must produce `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`), no guarantees are made as to the order in which the mapper function is applied to individual elements, or in what thread any behavioral parameter is executed for a given element

In other words, your example won’t work when using a parallel stream, even using an `AtomicInteger` as there is no guaranty regarding the *processing* order. The stream will maintain the *encounter* order, i.e. the resulting `List`’s order will reflect the original order of the `Bar`s in the original `List` but the `int` values generated via a side effect may not match (and the parallel performance might be poor, by the way).

The `forEachOrdered` terminal action is very special in that the action’s processing order will match the encounter order. This will limit the benefit of parallel processing dramatically when using this terminal action.

You can do what you want correctly using

```
public List<Foo> getFoos(List<Bar> bars) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bars.size()) //you may add .parallel()
        .mapToObj(idx -> bazUtils.getFoo(bars.get(idx), idx+1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation and solving code.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

> If a stream is ordered, most operations are constrained to operate on the elements in their encounter order; if the source of a stream is a List containing [1, 2, 3], then the result of executing map(x -> x*2) must be [2, 4, 6]. However, if the source has no defined encounter order, then any permutation of the values [2, 4, 6] would be a valid result.

So, yes; order is preserved by `map`.