# Java Stream: difference between forEach and forEachOrdered

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

**Premise**: I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797579/foreach-vs-foreachordered-in-java-8-stream) and others, but I need some clarifications.

I understand that `Stream.forEach` method makes the difference (not only) when dealing with parallel streams, and this explains why this

```
//1
Stream.of("one ","two ","three ","four ","five ","six ")
.parallel()
.forEachOrdered(item -> System.out.print(item));
```

prints

```
one two three four five six
```

But when it comes to intermediate operations, the order is not guaranteed anymore when stream is parallelized. So this code

```
//2
Stream.of("one ","two ","three ","four ","five ","six ")
.parallel()
.peek(item -> System.out.print(item))
.forEachOrdered(item -> System.out.print(""));
```

will print something like

```
four six five one three two
```

Is it correct to say that `forEachOrdered` method only affects order of elements in its own execution? Intuitively, I'm thinking of `//1` example being exactly the same as

```
//3
Stream.of("one ","two ","three ","four ","five ","six ")
.parallel()
.peek(item -> System.out.print("")) //or any other intermediate operation
.sequential()
.forEach(item -> System.out.print(item));
```

Is my intuition wrong? Am I missing something about the whole mechanism?

Comment: No, you can’t turn one op into parallel and another into sequential. The action passed to `forEachOrdered` still might be invoked by different threads, but they will synchronize appropriately.

Comment: @Holger, I don't get it...

Comment: Multiple threads, synchronizing at one point, are still something different than a single threaded execution.

Comment: @Holger I think I uderstand what you mean. But regarding my specific case, where I'm only interested in elements order without considering threads overlapping issues, are `//1` an `//3` conceptually equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

You are right in that the guarantees made for the action of `forEachOrdered` only apply to that action and nothing else. But it’s wrong to assume that this is the same as `.sequential().forEach(…)`.

`sequential` will turn the entire stream pipeline into sequential mode, thus, the action passed to `forEach` will be executed by the same thread, but also the preceding `peek`’s action. For most intermediate operations, the exact placement of `parallel` or `sequential` is irrelevant and specifying both makes no sense as only the last one will be relevant.

Also, there is still no guaranty made about the ordering when using `forEach`, even if it hasn’t any consequences in the current implementation. This is discussed in [“Does Stream.forEach respect the encounter order of sequential streams?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34247318/2711488)

The [documentation of `Stream.forEachOrdered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) states:

> This operation processes the elements one at a time, in encounter order if one exists. Performing the action for one element [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) performing the action for subsequent elements, but for any given element, the action may be performed in whatever thread the library chooses.

So the action may get invoked by different threads, as perceivable by `Thread.currentThread()` but not run concurrently.
Further, if the stream has an *encounter order*, it will get reconstituted at this place. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323641/2711488) sheds some light one the difference of *encounter order* and *processing order*.

Comment: "sequential will turn the entire stream pipeline into sequential mode", this is something that I was totally missing!

Answer (score 4):

The #3 code is not conceptually equivalent to #1, because `parallel()` or `sequential()` calls affect the whole stream, not just the subsequent operations. So in #3 case the whole procedure will be performed sequentially. Actually #3 case resembles the early design of the Stream API when you actually could change the parallel/sequential mode. This was considered to be unnecessary complication (and actually added problems, see, for example, [this discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-December/007374.html)) as usually you only need to change mode to make the terminal operation ordered (but not necessarily sequential). So `forEachOrdered()` was added and `parallel()/sequential()` semantics was changed to affect the whole stream (see [this changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/29664d18c7d1)).

Basically you're right: in parallel stream there's no order guarantee for intermediate operations. If you need to perform them in particular order, you have to use the sequential stream.