# Find first repeated character in a String using Java 8 or streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am having hard time in solving this question using java 8. I am aware of the similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529831/how-to-find-first-repeated-and-non-repeated-character-in-a-string-using-java8).
But that solution is not working as it returns "a" as first repeated character for below given input.
The expected output is "e".

pls help.

Given input = "I am feeling happy"; 
Expected output = "e"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no technical reason to use Java 8 streams.  The real purpose of Java 8 streams is to make code more concise and easier to read / understand.  If you don't understand streams well enough ... or the problem is ill-suited to streams ... then you don't achieve that goal by using streams.

But assuming that you want to try, here is >a< solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Feel the need";
        Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
        OptionalInt first = input.chars()
            .filter(i -> !seen.add(i))
            .findFirst();
        if (first.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println((char) first.getAsInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. `String.chars()` gives an `IntStream` ... !!
2. `Set.add` returns `false` if the element was already in the set.
3. So ... `filter(i -> !seen.add(i))` is filtering out characters that were not in `seen`; i.e. ones that aren't duplicate.
4. The `first()` gives us the first duplicate ... or an empty optional.
5. We need to cast the resulting `int` to a `char` to print it as a character.

Note: this is rather "dirty" because it depends on performing a side-effect on `seen`.  It will break if you attempt to parallelize the stream.  Also, we really should be streaming Unicode codepoints rather than `char` values.

---

In fact the expected output from your question **should** be a space character, because SP is the first repeated character in the string!

Answer (score 1):

Although you asked about a stream based solution, I believe that requirement is a symptom of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), because it can be done without a stream in one line:

```
String firstRepeated = str.replaceAll(".*?(.)(?=\\1).*|.*", "$1");
```

which returns the first repeated char, or the blank string if there is no repeated character.