# Java 8 findFirst and encounter order

Tags: java, java-8

The [JavaDocs for `findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) say that if the stream has an encounter order, then the first element will always be returned, but if the stream does not have an encounter order, any element may be returned.

I'm trying to demonstrate how this works on a stream without an encounter order, but I can't get it to return anything other than the actual first element.

I tried adding the elements to a `Set`, which does not have a defined encounter order:

```
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings"));
    Optional<String> firstString = words.stream()
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(firstString);
```

Every time I run, I get `a` as the first string. Then I tried doing a `Collections.shuffle` on the `List` before adding it to the `Set`, but that didn't change anything.

```
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings");
    words = new HashSet<>();
    words.addAll(wordList);
    firstString = words.stream()
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(firstString);
```

I still get back the word `a` every time.

Then I tried using the `unordered` method from `BaseStream`, which claims to return a stream without encounter order, but no difference:

```
    firstString = Stream.of("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings")
            .unordered()
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(firstString);
```

Now I get the word `this` every time. Am I missing something? Is there some way to demonstrate that `findFirst` on an unordered stream returns different values?

Comment: well... `a` and `this` are "any element" - the JavaDocs does not state that every time a different element will be returned, it is just (trying to) saying that there is no guarantee of which element will be returned

Comment: Agreed, but is there any way I can show a different result? Is the reference implementation that I'm using always going to assume an encounter order even on an explicitly unordered stream?

Comment: I'd try making a parallel unordered stream with a large collection and then filtering with some non-trivial predicate. Theoretically you should get multiple threads filtering/searching the stream in parallel and it should be less deterministic, who wins. Maybe introduce a random pause in the predicate.

Answer (score 26):

Well, “any” includes the possibility of “first”. Of course, the Stream implementation does not waste efforts in randomizing the data, so for a lot of cases, especially with sequential execution, it will still be the first element, if we can call it that way (as without an order, there is no distinguished first element).

Your best chances of exhibiting different results for `findFirst` are with parallel Streams. But even there, not every combination of operations is suitable of exhibiting the unorderedness.

One point is, that in the *current implementation*, the `findFirst()` *operation* does not change it’s behavior when the Stream is unordered, i.e. it does not actively try to be like `findAny()`. It may still exhibit unpredictable behavior due to the *source* of the Stream, but if your source is `Stream.of("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings")`, i.e. an immutable sequence of a known size, it has already the best parallel performance possible, so there’s simply no way of drawing a benefit of the chained `unordered()`, hence, the current implementation doesn’t change its behavior.

It might surprise, but this even applies to a `HashSet` to some degree. While it has an unspecified order, there will be an actual order within its backing array at some point of time and as long as you don’t modify the `Set`, there will be no reason to shuffle these entries around, so for a particular `HashSet` instance, you may repeatedly get the same “first” element, though it’s not specified which one and even within a single runtime, another `HashSet` instance representing the same contents, but having a different history, may have a different order.

---

One example of an operation that is known to draw a benefit from the unordered characteristics is `distinct`. While it has to sort out duplicates, it has to keep the *first* encountered of equal elements, if it makes a notable difference. This can degrade the performance significantly, hence, the implementation will immediately try to get a benefit if the stream is unordered. E.g.

```
List<String> equal=IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i->new String("test")) // don't do this in normal code
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, equal.size())
    .collect(IdentityHashMap::new, (m,i)->m.put(equal.get(i),i), Map::putAll);

equal.parallelStream().distinct().map(map::get)
     .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

This creates a bunch of `equal` but distinguishable `String` instances (which you normally shouldn’t do), registers them with their positional number in an `IdentityHashMap`, so we can find out, which instance `distinct` has retained. Since the code above uses an ordered stream created by a `List`, it consistently prints `0`, regardless of how often you execute it.

In contrast,

```
equal.parallelStream().unordered().distinct().map(map::get)
     .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

will print arbitrary numbers of the range, as we have released the *ordered* contract and allow to pick any of the equal strings.

---

As already noted before, this is all *implementation specific*. You should never make an assumption about whether an operation can actually draw a benefit and thus, will change its behavior for unordered streams. The explanation above was only meant to illustrate why sometimes the behavior of a particular implementation might not change for unordered stream. Though, it still might in the next version or a different JRE implementation.

Comment: I think it's about time to edit this great answer... things have already changed in jdk-9 for `findFirst` for example: `boolean mustFindFirst = StreamOpFlag.ORDERED.isKnown(helper.getStreamAndOpFlags()); return new FindTask<>(this, mustFindFirst, helper, spliterator).invoke();`

Comment: @Eugene: I think, I’ll make a sweeping swipe soon.

Comment: Holger Please never, but absolutely **never** delete this great answer. @Eugene pointed me here from a question I asked today, and I must say that reading this was enlightening.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: don’t worry, I just meant a great update round, no deletions.

Answer (score 12):

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895946/1441122) has already ably explained the situation. (+1) I'd like to provide a demonstration of `HashSet` instances that have the same contents but that have different iteration order. First we create a set as before:

```
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings");
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(wordList);
```

We create another set of words, add a bunch of stuff (doesn't matter exactly what it is), and then remove it:

```
    Set<String> words2 = new HashSet<>(wordList);
    IntStream.range(0, 50).forEachOrdered(i -> words2.add(String.valueOf(i)));
    words2.retainAll(wordList);
```

If we inspect the results as follows:

```
    System.out.println(words.equals(words2));
    System.out.println(words);
    System.out.println(words2);
```

we can see from the output that the sets are equal but iterate in a different order:

```
true
[a, strings, stream, of, this, is]
[this, is, strings, stream, of, a]
```

As noted elsewhere, if you get a stream from these and call `findFirst()`, the result is the first element in iteration order, which will clearly differ between these sets.

What happened is that by adding and removing a bunch of elements, we've caused the set to increase its internal table size, requiring the elements to be rehashed. The original elements end up in different relative positions in the new table, even after the new elements have been removed.

Although `HashSets` have no specified iteration order, the order is likely to be repeatable (and even predictable) if the set is initialized with the same contents in the same way every time. We thus say that the stream from a set has no defined encounter order, even though the order is often the same each time.

Note that in JDK 9, the new immutable sets (and maps) are actually randomized, so their iteration orders will change from run to run, even if they are initialized the same way every time.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: @StuartMarks has this randomization been done in other places too in jdk-9? Running this code `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); set.add("a");set.add("b");set.add("c");set.add("d"); for (;;) {String result = set.stream().parallel().findFirst().get();if (!result.equals("a")) {System.out.println(result);break;}}` with jdk-8 freezes, but stops pretty fast with jdk-9 (with a result != "a"). Notice that I am not using the new  immutable set.

Comment: @Eugene No randomization is done for any of the existing collections. In JDK 9, `HashSet` iteration order hasn't changed. Of course, the result of `findFirst` on an unordered stream isn't specified, and it may be nondeterministic. However, I see the same behavior you do, which is that JDK 8 consistently returns `a` and JDK 9 consistently returns `d`. Not sure why that is. It could be because of internal implementation changes in the fork-join framework code. It might also differ from machine to machine.

Comment: As an addendum, two equal `HashSet`s may have different order even without different capacities, when there is a bucket collision, but less than `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD` elements in the bucket. In that case, the elements in the bucket will reflect insertion order. When the number of elements in a bucket is between `UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD` and `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD`, we may even encounter an instance with a treeified bucket and another with a linked list bucket for the same contents. Also, when there is a true hash collision with non-`Comparable` elements, they will be in a linked list even within a tree.

Comment: @Holger having more the then `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD` elements in a bucket does not *imply* a Tree in that bucket. There's the `MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY` also. Take these Strings (not random): `[ABC, HNI, XZE, KPH, MAW, SCS, GVR, NCX, OEY, NZO]` and put them as Keys in HashMap. There will be a single bucket with 10 Nodes and it will *not* be a Tree. Just a minor correction I guess

Comment: @Eugene: interesting… but I think, we have now enough corner cases gathered.

Answer (score 9):

By marking your stream as unordered, you are not actually *making* it as such (you have not made the order in your Set any different), but instead you are removing any restriction that otherwise an ordered stream might impose.

The way to prove that this will return different results is to use a parallel stream.

```
 Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings"));
    Optional<String> firstString = words.stream().parallel()
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(firstString);
```

Running this a few times, shows:

```
  Optional[strings] and then Optional[this]
```

Changing your Set to a List and running in parallel will preserver the order:

```
 List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings"));
    Optional<String> firstString = words.stream().parallel()
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(firstString); // always Optional[this]
```

The absolute must read here is [Holger great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams/29218074#29218074)

Comment: Except that's not what I get. Adding all the words to a `Set` and running, even in parallel, still returns the same first word each time. That's why I was confused, before seeing Stuart Marks answer.

Comment: @kousen I feel like an idiot right now, i was running this code via jdk-9, where it exhibits the behavior. Indeed tried it with jdk-8 and it does not. Weird enough, I am not using any new immutable collections, so probably other things have changes as well.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Stuart Marks mentioned that difference between 8 and 9 in his answer, which I had no idea about

Comment: @kousen yes he does say about differences, but that is about *immutable new collections*; he is referring to structures like `Map.of(Key, Value)` or `Set.of(E1, E2)`. But in my code and yours, we are not using any of these, so I assume the randomization is performed in other places too.

Answer (score 3):

As @Eugene already mentioned, calling `unordered` does not necessarily change the actual physical ordering of the elements. Don't forget that `unordered` is an intermediate operation that does nothing until a terminal operation is invoked.

Therefore I tend to think of it this way:

1. When creating a `Set` containing the elements `"this", "is", "a", "stream", "of", "strings"`, then it happens that the first element in the `Set` when iterating over it is `"a"`, so `findFirst` just returns that value.
2. When you create a stream using `Stream.of("this", "is", "stream", "of", "strings")`, it returns a stream with an ordering restriction which will be respected by `findFirst`. Calling `unordered` removes that restriction, but the element `"this"` is still physically the first element because `unordered` did not necessarily change the ordering in the source array.

A slighly better example might be the following:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
words.addAll(Arrays.asList("this", "is", "stream", "of", "strings"));

Optional<String> firstString1 = words.stream().findFirst();
// Optional[strings]
System.out.println(firstString1);

Optional<String> firstString2 = words.stream()
                                     .sorted().findFirst();
// Optional[is]
System.out.println(firstString2);

Optional<String> firstString3 = Stream.of("this", "is", "stream", "of", "strings")
                                      .findFirst();
// Optional[this]
System.out.println(firstString3);

Optional<String> firstString4 = Stream.of("this", "is", "stream", "of", "strings")
                                      .unordered().findFirst();
// Optional[this]
System.out.println(firstString4);
```

Note how the `sorted()` method changes the result because it enforces the ordering restriction, unlike the `unordered` method which had no effect.