# Which stream operations use `CONCURRENT`,`IMMUTABLE` and `NONNULL` Spliterator characteristics?

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

Which stream operations use `CONCURRENT`,`IMMUTABLE` and `NONNULL` Spliterator characteristics? How does each of them help in those operations?

---

**I'm not asking what those flags are, this can be found easly in the documantation. I'm asking which operations use them and how.**

Comment: Maybe be the doc would answer you ;)

Comment: Found my answer only for the rest of the characteristics :)

Comment: As far as I know, `IMMUTABLE` and `NONNULL` characteristics are not used at all (but may be used in the future Java versions).

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Thanks for the information. Is there a reference to a place you read it? Also I suspect that `CONCURRENT` characteristic is also not used at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should make a clear distinction that you are asking about `Spliterator` characteristics here and these depend on the *source* of the Stream; because there are also (`CONCURRENT`, `UNORDERED` and `IDENTITY_FINISH` for `Collectors` for example).

There is a comment in `StreamOpFlag` saying:

```
// The following Spliterator characteristics are not currently used but a
// gap in the bit set is deliberately retained to enable corresponding
// stream flags if//when required without modification to other flag values.
//
// 4, 0x00000100 NONNULL(4, ...
// 5, 0x00000400 IMMUTABLE(5, ...
// 6, 0x00001000 CONCURRENT(6, ...
// 7, 0x00004000 SUBSIZED(7, ...
```

As far as I understand these are not a direct 1 to 1 mapping with the ones from Spliterator, but still they are not used.

*At the moment*  (and I've searched the jdk-8 and 9 sources), neither are leveraged - but still are reported by some implementations of Spliterators (`Arrays` report `IMMUTABLE` and `ConcurrentHashMap` reports `NONNULL` for example).

These flags could be used in the future on the other hand - if you know that a source can not contain null elements (`NONNULL`), obviously you can skip some null checks or define *some state* with a null. I can't think of any examples for `CONCURRENT` or `IMMUTABLE`, but there might be such.

For example under the current implementation for an `UNORDERED` and `CONCURRENT` collector (!= `Spliterator` properties), the `combiner` is not called when you do `toConcurrentMap`. For example:

```
Set.of("one", "two", "das", "dasda")
            .stream()
            .parallel()
            .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Function.identity(), String::length));
```

will not call the `combiner` - since there is no need to.

Optimizations like these could be made for any of the 3 characteristics  that you have mentioned. For example you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944973/search-for-example-of-inconsistent-behavior-java-8-stream) where `StreamOpFlag.ORDERED` has changed the result of `findFirst` in java 8 vs java 9

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, the stream operations use neither of these 3 characteristics. This can be checked by searching these constants in the Java sources.

However, the `CONCURRENT` characteristic may affect the behaviour of parallel streams when you write your own collection. If you create a `Spliterator` from a collection and **not** report the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, then the spliterator will additionally have `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED` characteristics:

```
Collection<Integer> col = ...
Spliterator<Integer> s = Spliterators.spliterator(col, 0);

System.out.println(s.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)); // Prints true
System.out.println(s.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SUBSIZED)); // Prints true
```

But if you report the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, then the spliterator is not `SIZED` anymore:

```
Collection<Integer> col = ...
Spliterator<Integer> s = Spliterators.spliterator(col, Spliterator.CONCURRENT);

System.out.println(s.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)); // Prints false
System.out.println(s.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SUBSIZED)); // Prints false
```

Spliterators that are not `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED` are poorly parallelized, so when you write you own concurrent collection, it is better to write a custom spliterator and not rely on the default spliterator implementation.

Comment: well... that's *specific* to `Spliterators.spliterator(Collection)` because they create the Spliterator from the `Iterator`; that's not a general rule. Usually collections implement their own Spliterators much better.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I noted this in my answer (last sentence)

Answer (score 1):

People say that `IMMUTABLE` isn't used but as it turns out, `Stream#iterate` reports `IMMUTABLE`:

```
jshell> Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).spliterator().characteristics()
$1 ==> 1040
```

1040 is `IMMUTABLE | ORDERED` but it looks like any operation drops `IMMUTABLE` (tested with `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, `limit`, `skip`; tested on Java 16)
`IntStream#iterate`, `LongStream#iterate` and `DoubleStream#iterate` report `NONNULL` as well but that is also dropped by the next operation.