# Encounter order friendly/unfriendly terminal operations vs parallel/sequential vs ordered/unordered streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944973/search-for-example-of-inconsistent-behavior-java-8-stream), I started to play with ordered vs unordered streams, parallel vs sequential streams and terminal operations that respect encounter order vs terminal operations that don't respect it.

In one answer to the linked question, a code similar to this one is shown:

```
List<Integer> ordered = Arrays.asList(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> result = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

ordered.parallelStream().forEach(result::add);

System.out.println(ordered);
System.out.println(result);
```

And the lists are indeed different. The `unordered` list even changes from one run to another, showing that the result is actually non-deterministic.

So I created this other example:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> result2 = ordered.parallelStream()
        .unordered()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));

System.out.println(ordered);
System.out.println(result2);
```

And I expected to see similar results, as the stream is both parallel and unordered (maybe `unordered()` is redundant, since it's already parallel). However, the resulting list is ordered, i.e. it's equal to the source list.

So my question is why the collected list is ordered? Does `collect` always respect encounter-order, even for parallel, unordered streams? Is it the specific `Collectors.toCollection(...)` collector the one that forces encounter-order?

Comment: Very interesting questions, but the last one is off-topic. You'd better remove it from your post.

Comment: Yes, it would be better.

Comment: btw, it is slowly becoming the standard on SO for streams; here is an absolute must read from Holger : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894173/java-8-findfirst-and-encounter-order

Comment: `unordered()` is *not* redundant, as parallel does not imply unordered. That has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/2711488). It’s wrong to say that an unordered terminal operation “does not respect” the encounter order. Its unordered characteristic implies that the order has no meaning for the result, like when summing ints or collecting to a `HashSet`. When you are saying `unordered()` explicitly, you are also saying that the order is irrelevant, even if you can recognize an order in the result list. And if the order is irrelevant to you, there’s no question about it…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collectors.toCollection` returns a `Collector` which lacks the `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` characteristic.  Another collector which specified `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` might behave differently.

That said: "unordered" means *no guarantees*, not *guaranteed to vary.*  If the library finds it easiest to treat an unordered collection as ordered, it is allowed to do so, and that behavior is allowed to change release to release, on Tuesdays, or if there is a full moon.

(Note also that `Collectors.toCollection` does not require you to use a concurrent collection implementation if you're going to use parallel streams; `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` would work fine.  That's because the collector doesn't have the `Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT` characteristic, so it uses a collection strategy that works for non-concurrent collections even with parallel streams.)

If you use an unordered stream but a collector that isn't `UNORDERED`, or vice versa, I doubt you get any guarantees from the framework.  If there were a table, it would say "HERE BE <strike>DRAGONS</strike> UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR."  I'd also expect some differences for different kinds of chained operations here, e.g. Eugene mentions `findFirst` varies here, even though `findFirst` is inherently an ordered operation -- `unordered().findFirst()` becomes equivalent to `findAny()`.

For `Stream.collect`, I believe the current implementation has three strategies it chooses between:

- Sequential: starts one accumulator, accumulates elements into it (in encounter order, because why would you bother doing work to shuffle the elements? just accept them in the order you get them), calls the finisher.
- Parallel execution, concurrent collector, and the stream or the collector are unordered: one accumulator, shards the input, worker threads process the elements from each shard and add elements to the accumulator when they're ready, calls the finisher.
- Parallel execution, anything else: shards the input into N shards, each shard gets sequentially accumulated into its own *distinct* accumulator, the accumulators get combined with the combiner function, calls the finisher.

Comment: So, in this case, the fact that the order is preserved is an implementation detail that could change later, right? toCollection commits to respecting the order, but the stream is unordered, so the output might be in a different order from the source, right?

Comment: @JBNizet I'd say yes, that would be spec-compliant.

Comment: @JBNizet exactly. In the linked answer this exact diff is provided using `findFirst` that actually changed from 8 to 9.

Comment: @JBNizet On a side note, implementations are allowed to do that *generally*. Another example would be `AtomicInteger#weakCompareAndSet` and `AtomicInteger#compareAndSet` that did the *same thing* before java-9.

Comment: @Eugene I was more referring to the presence of the word "first" in the method name as making it intuitively an ordered operation.  I already said that `unordered().findFirst()` is equivalent to `findAny()`, an unordered operation.  We're on the same page, we just phrased it differently.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ah! makes sense, I'll remove the comment then.

Answer (score 4):

Under the *current implementation* I've checked java-8 and java-9 the unordered flag is ignored for the `collect` phase for non-concurrent collectors (`Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` is not set).  The implementations are allowed to do that, somehow similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883618/parallel-stream-non-concurrent-unordered-collector).

In the same question that you linked, I did provide the example of how `findFirst` *actually* changed from jdk-8 to jdk-9.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation [Stream#collect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) has already mentioned:

> When executed in parallel, multiple intermediate results may be **instantiated**, **populated**, and **merged** so as to maintain isolation of mutable data structures. Therefore, even when executed in parallel with non-thread-safe data structures (such as ArrayList), **no additional synchronization** is needed for a parallel reduction.

which means the `Stream#collect` does two primary thing: `split` & `merge`.

but I have a special example in jdk-8 that you can fetch the different results, :). when creates a **unordered** stream by [Stream#generate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-), then you can fetch different result on `Collectors#toList`, for example:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(__ -> {
        return unordered().parallel().collect(toSet());
}).collect(toSet());

assert result.each.size() == 100000; // ok
//                   v--- surprised, it was pass 
assert result.size() > 1;
```

---

```
Stream<Integer> unordered() {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    return Stream.generate(counter::getAndIncrement).limit(10000);
}
```