# Java8 Transform list of object to list of one attribute of object

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to use Java 8 tricks to do the following in one line.

Given this object definition:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyObj {
    private String id;
    private Double value;
}
```

and a `List<MyObj> objects`, I want to get a `List<String> objectIds` which is a list of all `id`s of the objects in the first list - in the same order.

I can do this using a loop in Java but I believe there should be a one-liner lambda in Java8 that can do this. I was not able to find a solution online. Perhaps I wasn't using the right search terms.

Could someone suggest a lambda or another one-liner for this transform?

Comment: the search terms for this is not 'lambda' but 'stream api'.  lots of answers in that vein here.

Comment: What are all these annotations? `Getter`? `Setter`?

Comment: Is that from Lombok?

Comment: @user2357112: that's `Lombok`'s annotation. Pretty common these days.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`objects.stream().map(MyObj::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

that said, the **method reference** `::` operator allows you to reference any method in your classpath and use it as a lambda for the operation that you need.

As mentioned in the comments, a stream preserves order.

Comment: I am first ordering the list in descending order of `value` using `objects.sort((o1, o2) -> (int) (o1.getValue()-o2.getValue()))`. I then need to extract only the objectIds to pass into another function without changing the order. If this method does not guarantee order, then I can't risk using it.

Comment: Per this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/539864 it seems that in lists order is guaranteed

Comment: @Nik that comparator is better written `objects.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyObj::getValue))`.  But yes, order is guaranteed.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: thanks. I always used to wonder why there isn't a much better comparator available for `double`s. Will use this henceforth in all my sorts.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Follow-up. How can I ensure descending order sort in that comparator? I believe by default it would be sorting in ascending order, right?

Comment: `comparingInt(MyObj::getValue()).reversed()`