# How to convert this code to JAVA 8 Stream API?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert this while loop to equivalent code using a Java 8 `Stream`s, but I don't know how to both stream the `List` *and* remove elements from it.

```
private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

while (nameList.size() > 0) {
    String nameListFirstEntry = nameList.get(0);
    nameList.remove(0);
    setNameCombinations(nameListFirstEntry);
}
```

Comment: Convert it to what? SQL? COBOL? Pascal?

Comment: This is already valid Java8 code (although I don't know what it does and why it does it).

Comment: In java-8 stream or foreach

Comment: what is your code trying to do? what is `setNameCombinations`?

Comment: Neither streams nor `forEach` are allowed to modify the source list, so you're out of luck on failthful conversion.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov actually, [you *can* do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43345980/256196).

Comment: @Bohemian, I see now. Yes, it is possible with the way you do it. I was referring to "intrinsic collection streams", I guess, ignoring other possible opportunities.

Comment: Looks like a nice question about transforming ugly and inefficient Java 7 code into ugly and inefficient Java 8 code :-)

Answer (score 6):

I guess this will do

```
nameList.forEach(this::setNameCombinations);
nameList.clear();
```

In case you don't need the original list anymore, you might as well create a new empty list instead.

Comment: Doesn't fullfill the requirement _stream the list and remove elements from it_.

Comment: ok, iterating AND deletion are two seperate concerns, I wonder why both have to be satisfied in the same stream? the actual question was "convert while loop to equivalent code using stream api", and there you go. You never asked for doing it in the same stream ... which I doubt being a sensible requirement anyway (though I have to admit Bohemian's approach is quite interessting)

Comment: You're right, but the question also says _but I don't know how to both stream the list and remove elements from it_.

Comment: Stream API is a reading API, it's not intended for modifying the source.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, I really like your clean and concise approach, but I think [Bohemian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43345980/4105457) fulfills the requirements.

Comment: Yes, agreed. His solution is clever and perfectly fulfills the requirement. The requirements (contraints) are nonsense nonetheless. It's one of those theoretical examples where you think "nice to know, but never do this in practice" ;)

Comment: @Gerald You're correct that a stream shouldn't modify the source, but that's not what's going on in my code. The stream in my answer does not modify the source. The supplier does, which is completely different. The stream code is deterministic and obeys guidelines. The supplier code is simple and could even have used a method reference, but the code is briefer as is.

Answer (score 4):

Because [`List#remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) also returns the element, you can both stream the list's elements *and* remove them via a stream:

```
Stream.generate(() -> nameList.remove(0))
    .limit(nameList.size())
    .forEach(this::setNameCombinations);
```

This code doesn't break any "rules". From the javadoc of [Stream#generate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-):

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier. This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

There is no mention of any restrictions on *how* the supplier is implemented or that is must have no side effects etc. The Supplier's only contract is to supply.

---

For those who doubt this is "works", here's some test code using 100K elements showing that indeed order is preserved:

```
int size = 100000;
List<Integer> list0 = new ArrayList<>(size); // the reference list
IntStream.range(0, size).boxed().forEach(list0::add);
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list0); // will feed stream
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(size);  // will consume stream

Stream.generate(() -> list1.remove(0))
        .limit(list1.size())
        .forEach(list2::add);

System.out.println(list0.equals(list2)); // always true
```

Comment: @Eugene So don't add `parallel()`. It is not "illegal", or even mysterious. It is using `List#remove()` as the stream's Supplier... big deal. Try it yourself if you have doubts.

Comment: @eugene Let's get something straight here: This code does not stream the list, and the stream is not modifying anything. The Supplier is mutating something as it supplies, but the stream doesn't know or care how the Supplier supplies. There is nothing here that breaks any guidelines or contracts.

Comment: @Eugene why do you believe that adding parallel should get the same result? Where does it say that? I can tell you that adding parallel usually does change the result - that is the encounter order of the elements of the stream becomes non-deterministic, if the particular stream supports parallelism (the stream if a List for example does not).

Comment: assuming the `nameList` is made out of 3 elements `[a,b,c]`; by the same result Im expecting to see these 3 elements in any order (since it's parallel)

Comment: @OleV.V. How is it possible to exhaust this `List` except another thread? This has to be prohibited by a proper synchronization.

Comment: @Bohemian To ensure encounting order of elements you should use `Stream::forEachOrdered`.

Comment: @Flown adding `forEachOrdered` can still fail in a parallel pipeline with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Eugene If you're removing the exact amount of elements of the `List` how is this possible?

Comment: @Flown (even if I can re-produce that quite easily right now - to throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException), the point is that `nameList` is a non-thread safe collection, `remove` is not `atomic` - the result later is completely un-defined.

Comment: @Eugene As I said you have to do proper synchronization during `Stream` processing, but this is a general problem not specific to this question.

Comment: @Eugene see update to question with test code that shows this with works, preserving order, with 100K elements. See if you can write a test case that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Flown see update to question with test code that shows this with works, preserving order, with 100K elements. See if you can write a test case that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Bohemian `List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList.add("a");
        nameList.add("b");
        nameList.add("c");

        Stream.generate(() -> nameList.remove(0))
                .parallel()
                .limit(nameList.size())
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);`  let's make that much simpler.

Comment: @Eugene huh? I deliberately didn't use `parallel()` because OP's code is order-sensitive. Why do you keep introducing it when it's not part of my answer? Also, this is not about creating a stream that may be used elsewhere. This is about replacing a specific isolated block of code, with the Stream used in-place then discarded.

Comment: @Eugener, shouldn't `parallel()` stage come after `limit()`, not before?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it does not matter.

Comment: @Bohemian `Stream::forEachOrdered` should be used, if you want to switch to `Stream::parallel`.

Comment: @Bohemian parallel was added to prove that this violates some spec. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams/29218074#29218074. I will make this my last comment also