# Java 8 Stream - parallel execution - different result - why?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Let's say i have a `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();` and i want to add values to it and compare the results of parallel execution using `forEach()` and `Collectors.toList()`.

First i add to this list some values from an sequential IntStream and forEach:

```
 IntStream.range(0,10).boxed().forEach(ints::add);
```

And i get the correct result:

```
ints ==> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now i `.clear()` the list and do the same thing in parallel:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().boxed().forEach(ints::add);
```

Now due to multithreading i get the incorrect result:

```
ints ==> [6, 5, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0]
```

Now i switch to collecting the same Stream of Integers:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).parallel().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And i get the correct result:

```
ints ==> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Question:**
Why does the two parallel executions produce different result's and why is the `Collector` producing the correct result?

If `forEach` produces a random result the `Collector` should too. I didn't specify any sorting and i think internally he is adding to a list like i did manually using `forEach`. Since he's doing it in parallel he's `add` method should get the values in unspecified order. Testing done i JShell.

EDIT:
No duplicate here. I understand the linked question. WHy does the Collector produce the correct result? If he would be producing another random result i would not be asking.

Comment: `Collector` is designed to handle parallelism. It's part of the streams API, and it's why they have the `combiner()`.

Comment: Okay, maybe the linked post if not 100% answering your question but it's at least 80% there and the remaining just requires a bit more research. nevertheless, reverted...

Comment: Collectors force the correct ordering to happen unless they're specifically constructed as order-independent.

Comment: Set<Characteristics> c = Collectors.toList().characteristics();
System.out.println(c);
[IDENTITY_FINISH]

Comment: I feel like the title of this question could be a bit different regarding the answer of @teppic that i wanted. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj well it should have been a more _specific_ question and description in the first place. You modifying your post consistently which changes the topic entirely is something you should avoid for future posts. Also, if #teppic answer is what you were after, then it's a good gesture to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `collect` operation *would* produce unordered output if the `Collector` you passed it had different characteristics. That is, if the `CONCURRENT` and `UNORDERED` flags were set (see `Collector.characteristics()`).

Under the hood `Collectors.toList()` is constructing a `Collector` roughly equivalent to this:

```
Collector.of(
    // Supplier of accumulators
    ArrayList::new,
    // Accumulation operation
    List::add,
    // Combine accumulators
    (left, right) -> {
        left.addAll(right);
        return left;
    }
)
```

A bit of logging reveals the lengths that the `collect` operation is going to to maintain thread safety and stream order:

```
Collector.of(
    () -> {
        System.out.printf("%s supplying\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    },
    (l, o) -> {
        System.out.printf("%s accumulating %s to %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), o, l);
        l.add(o);
    },
    (l1, l2) -> {
        System.out.printf("%s combining %s & %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), l1, l2);
        l1.addAll(l2);
        return l1;
    }
)
```

logs:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 2 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 6 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 4 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 5 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 3 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 combining [3] & [4]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 combining [2] & [3, 4]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 combining [5] & [6]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 1 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 8 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 9 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 combining [8] & [9]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 7 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 combining [7] & [8, 9]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 combining [5, 6] & [7, 8, 9]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 0 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 combining [0] & [1]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 combining [0, 1] & [2, 3, 4]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 combining [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] & [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can see that each read from the stream is written to a new accumulator, and that they are carefully combined to maintain order.

If we set the `CONCURRENT` and `UNORDERED` characteristic flags the collect method is free to take shortcuts; only one accumulator is allocated and ordered combination is unnecessary.

Using:

```
Collector.of(
    () -> {
        System.out.printf("%s supplying\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    },
    (l, o) -> {
        System.out.printf("%s accumulating %s to %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), o, l);
        l.add(o);
    },
    (l1, l2) -> {
        System.out.printf("%s combining %s & %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), l1, l2);
        l1.addAll(l2);
        return l1;
    },
    Characteristics.CONCURRENT,
    Characteristics.UNORDERED
)
```

Logs:

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 supplying
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 6 to []
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 2 to [6]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 5 to [6, 2]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 4 to [6, 2, 5]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 3 to [6, 2, 5, 4]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 1 to [6, 2, 5, 4, 3]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 0 to [6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 8 to [6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 accumulating 7 to [6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 8]
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 accumulating 9 to [6, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 8, 7]
```

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd recommend going through [Why is shared mutability bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219903/why-is-shared-mutability-bad)
.

Second, [there is an example provided by the authors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) under the "Side-effects" section which pretty much is doing something similar to what you're doing:

> As an example of how to transform a stream pipeline that
>   inappropriately uses side-effects to one that does not, the following
>   code searches a stream of strings for those matching a given regular
>   expression, and puts the matches in a list.

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
 stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
       .forEach(s -> results.add(s));  // Unnecessary use of side-effects!
```

> If executed in parallel, the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would
>   cause incorrect results, and adding needed synchronization would cause
>   contention, undermining the benefit of parallelism. Furthermore, using
>   side-effects here is completely unnecessary; the forEach() can simply
>   be replaced with a reduction operation that is safer, more efficient,
>   and more amenable to parallelization:

```
List<String>results =
         stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());  // No side-effects!
```

So, you may still ask "Why does the Collector produce the correct result?".

Simply because the authors already have something in place to handle parallelism.

Comment: I could comment why I sort of disagree here, but instead...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494189/1059372

Comment: @Eugene disagree with what exactly ?

Comment: sorry... with the explanation itself

Comment: @Eugene for example...?

Answer (score 4):

First things first, `forEach` *is documented* as :

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic

So in a future version of jdk, even your non-parallel code could produce "incorrect" results, that is out-of-order results. Under the current implementation, only the parallel version will produce these kind of results; but again this is no guarantee, `forEach` is free to do whatever it wants internally, unlike `forEachOrdered` for example.

Preserving order or not is **not** a property of sequential or parallel, it solely depends on the operation that break this order or not; that's it (like explicitly calling `unordered` for example).

`Collectors.toList` on the other hand is a terminal operation that preserve the order. Generally, unless a terminal operation *is explicit* in it's documentation about order, it will preserver it. So for example, see `Stream::generate`:

> Returns an infinite sequential **unordered** stream.

That being said, there are two orders in general,  order in which *intermediate* operations are being processed and *terminal* operations are. The first ones are not defined, you can modify your example and check:

```
IntStream.range(0,10)
         .parallel()
         .peek(System.out::println) // out of order printing
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

while the terminal operations order is preserved.

And the last point is that this:

```
....parallel().forEach(ints::add)
```

you simply got lucky to *even see all the elements* in the first place. You are adding from different threads multiple elements to a non-thread safe collection (`ArrayList`); you could have easily missed elements or have nulls in your `ints`. I bet that running this some number of times, would prove this.

Even if you switch to let's say `Collections.synchronizedList(yourList)`, *the order* in which these will appear is still undefined, for the reasons stated above about `forEach`