# How to make a data class singleton in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, singleton, data-class

Assume I have a data class:

```
data class SensorData(val name: String, val temp : Double)
```

I create this `SensorData` object from either an REST service or by internal setter method, whereas `name` is always populated and `temp` might be empty.

Further on, I need this SensorData object through several classes, thats I thought of using a `singleton`.

Obviously I need `object` keyword [as described here](https://antonioleiva.com/objects-kotlin/), but how can I combine `data class object` ?

Comment: Using a singleton is just wrong for this purpose. Just pass the instance to the classes that need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **companion object** to keep a reference to your data object:

```
data class SensorData(val name: String, var temp : Double) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        @JvmStatic
        private var INSTANCE: SensorData? = null

        @JvmStatic
        @JvmOverloads
        fun getInstance(name: String = "default", temp : Double = 0.0): SensorData = INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: SensorData(name, temp).also { INSTANCE = it }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val name1 = SensorData.getInstance("name", 5.0).name

// Or with default values:
val name2 = SensorData.getInstance().name
```

Comment: What happens when the temperature changes without knowing sensors name?

Comment: If you want to change the temperature use `SensorData.getInstance().temp = 36.6`. But in this case name will be set as `"default"` or whatever you provide as default value if `INSTANCE` has not been initialized yet.

Answer (score 4):

I think you got the concept of a Singleton wrong:

*"The singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance"*

It is not only meant to be used to make it public to all classes, but to limit the number of instances.

A data class is a class to store data, why should it be a Singleton?

Rethink your architecture to make it accessible where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I guess!

```html
object SensorDataSingleton {
    var data: SensorData? = null
}

data class SensorData(val name: String, val temp: Double?)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a data class as a singleton. That's not what they are designed for. A better approach would be to create a wrapper object around your data class, which handles your SensorData-Object(s). This will also allow you to use multiple SensorData objects (maybe needed in future) or replace the current one with a new one if you poll the REST-Service a second time.

```
object SensorDataService {
 var sensorData: SensorData? = null
}

data class SensorData(val name: String, val temp : Double)
```

Comment: You should never put mutable data in a singleton object. Global shared mutable data is a big no-no.

Comment: @marstran It surely is, but it's also an answer to the original question. The setter to the sensorData can be private as long as some initialization logic is provided.

Comment: @marstran Is there an example somewhere why not?

Comment: @NoamSilverstein Here's an SO question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219903/why-is-shared-mutability-bad

Comment: Shared mutable data exposes your data to concurrent write access. The data can be changed by multiple threads at the same time. Imagine you share an int variable (i = 3). One thread adds +1 and the other multiplies by 2. Depending on which thread is faster you either have (3 + 1) * 2 = 8 or 3 * 2 + 1 = 7. Which result is the correct one: 7 or 8? How do you handle the case of an incorrect calculation?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should rethink your architecture as data class is used to store data so why it should be a singleton? It is not only meant to be used to make it public to all classes but to limit the number of instances.