# Does partitioningBy preserve order of elements in the original list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have ordered list of LocalDateTime and I need to split it on midnight of specific date. The order of elements in two new lists should not be changed.

```
List<LocalDateTime> l = Arrays.asList(LocalDateTime.of(2017,10,24,7,0,0),LocalDateTime.of(2017,10,24,8,0,0),LocalDateTime.of(2017,10,25,7,0,0),LocalDateTime.of(2017,10,25,9,0,0));
```

Does Collectors.partitioningBy provide a guarantee that the order will be preserved?

```
l.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(t-> t.isAfter(LocalDateTime.of(2017,10,25,0,0,0))))
```

Output:

```
{false=[2017-10-24T07:00, 2017-10-24T08:00], true=[2017-10-25T07:00, 2017-10-25T09:00]}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It _probably will_ preserve the order in simplest cases, like single-thread iterating stream from an ordered source, but stream by itself doesn't guarantee you any particular ordering (unless you ask it to, of course), and neither does a Collector.

Comment: If the input list is ordered, a binary search would be much more efficient than `Collectors.partitioningBy`, and once you find the index of the split date, you can create two sub-lists of the original list.

Comment: @MProkhorov: streams *will* maintain the encounter order, if they have one, even if the processing order might be different. That’s an important property of streams. See [How to ensure order of processing in java8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/2711488)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation of the built-in collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html) explicitly mentions when a `Collector` is an *unordered* collector, e.g. for [`toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) or [`groupingByConcurrent(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent-java.util.function.Function-). All collectors not specified to be *unordered* will preserve the encounter order, if the stream is ordered and they don’t have a downstream collector that is itself *unordered*.

`partitioningBy(predicate)` is equivalent to `partitioningBy(predicate, toList())` and hence, will maintain the encounter order.

A counter-example would be `partitioningBy(predicate, toSet())` which does not preserve any order and likewise, a stream that itself is unordered, e.g. `hashSet.stream() .collect(partitioningBy(predicate))`, does not make any guarantees about the result order.