# Preserve order in Java stream with collect

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I am running into a bit of an issue where I need order preserved in an operation being performed on a list of strings and using the `collect` method from the java streams api.

```
public List<String> countOccurrences(ArrayList<String> messages) {
        List<String> stackedMessages = new LinkedList<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> messageOccurrences = 
                   messages.stream()
                           .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), summingInt(e -> 1)));

        messageOccurrences.forEach((key, value) -> {
            String appendString = value == 1 ? "" : " (" + value + " times)";
            stackedMessages.add(key + appendString);
        });

        return stackedMessages;
    }
```

The problem with the above code is if I process a list such as `["blah", "blah", "yep"]`, it returns `["yep", "blah (2 times)"]` where I need it to return `["blah (2 times)", "yep"]`.

I looked at this post here already and was lead to believe if I am using a stream on an already ordered data structure then order would be ensured: [How to ensure order of processing in java8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams)

I'm thinking I need to change `groupingBy` to `toMap` and as of right now I am reading through that documentation. Anybody who is well versed in the subject matter already please offer some pointers.

UPDATE:

Thanks to the user @Aominè, this is the correct way to do it using groupingBy

```
.collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new, summingInt(e->1)))
```

Comment: you are iterating a HashMap, there is no order.

Comment: Use .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new, summingInt(e->1)))

Comment: saving the day again @Aominè, thank you

Comment: The usual remark : [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to collect to a `LinkedHashMap` to get the expected result. Also, you don’t have to do another `forEach` separately from the stream pipeline after the `groupingBy`, just create a stream from the `entrySet` and `map` then collect to list.

```
return messages.stream()
               .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, summingInt(e -> 1)))
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .map(e -> e.getKey()+(e.getValue() == 1 ? "" : " (" + e.getValue() +" times)"))
               .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I’d use `counting()` instead of `summingInt(e -> 1)`. And for the last mapping function, `e.getValue()==1? e.getKey(): e.getKey()+" ("+e.getValue()+" times)"` avoids unnecessary string concatenation.