# Factorize code where the only differences are Stream reduction operation

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a bunch of methods where the only difference is a Stream reduction operation :

```
static Stream<TimeValues> avg(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize) {
    return data
            .collect(SlidingCollector.batch(batchSize))
            .stream()
            .map(tvl -> {
                    OptionalDouble od = tvl.stream()
                    ...
                        .mapToDouble(tv -> tv.doubleValue())
                        .average(); // <-------
                    ...      
            });
}
```

```
static Stream<TimeValues> max(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize) {
    return data
            .collect(SlidingCollector.batch(batchSize))
            .stream()
            .map(tvl -> {
                    OptionalDouble od = tvl.stream()
                    ...
                        .mapToDouble(tv -> tv.doubleValue())
                        .max(); // <-------
                    ...      
            });
}
```

How to factorize this code and have a parametrized reduction operation (min, max, average, sum) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside -You might want to move `data.collect(SlidingCollector.batch(batchSize))` to a different method as well. With a more slightly hypothetical input, you could have possibly [implemented custom SummaryStatistics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51378142/1746118) too.

Comment: Thanks @Naman - I will give it a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--) and [`max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#max--) are `Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble>` type methods, so:

```
static Stream<TimeValues> avg(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize) {
    return reduce(data, batchSize, DoubleStream::average);
}

static Stream<TimeValues> max(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize) {
    return reduce(data, batchSize, DoubleStream::max);
}

private static Stream<TimeValues> reduce(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize,
                                         Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> reducer) {
    return data
            .collect(SlidingCollector.batch(batchSize))
            .stream()
            .map(tvl -> {
                    OptionalDouble od = reducer.apply(tvl.stream()
                    ...
                        .mapToDouble(tv -> tv.doubleValue()));
                    ...      
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas -  I was trying to use DoubleStream::reduce() but could only make it work with Double::min and Double::max

Answer (score 3):

The methods `.average` and `.max` are both `Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble>` , you can so store them in this type :

```
Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> avg = DoubleStream::average; // ie ds -> ds.average()
Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> mx = DoubleStream::max;
```

The use it as a parameter and use `.apply` with the `DoubleStream` as parameter

```
static Stream<TimeValues> method(Stream<TimeValues> data, int batchSize, 
                                 Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> fct) {
    return data
            .collect(SlidingCollector.batch(batchSize))
            .stream()
            .map(tvl -> {
                OptionalDouble od = fct.apply(tvl.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue));
            });
}
```

So the calls will be

```
Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> avg = ds -> ds.average();
Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> mx = DoubleStream::max;

method(...,10, avg);
method(...,10, mx);
```