# Java Stream: filter maps in list group by key

Tags: java, java-stream

There's a list(List<Map<String, String>>) as below:

```
[
{
   "name": "Wall Street",
   "point" "Walls Street",
   "similarity" : "0.945"
},
{
   "name": "Wall Street",
   "point" "Walldd Street",
   "similarity" : "0.871
},
{
   "name": "Duck Street",
   "point" "Ducks duck",
   "similarity" : "0.765
},
{
   "name": "Duck Street",
   "point" "yelow duck",
   "similarity" : "0.563
}
...
]
```

How to filter the list, to get the highest `similarity` map  group by `name`, and then combine to a list using Java Stream?
The result example is:

```
[
{
   "name": "Wall Street",
   "point" "Walls Street",
   "similarity" : 0.945
},

{
   "name": "Duck Street",
   "point" "Ducks duck",
   "similarity" : 0.765
}
...
]
```

ps:If there's same `similarity` value in multiple maps, keep them all int the list.

Initial code:

```
    List<HashMap<String, String>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("name", "Wall Street");
    map1.put("point", "Walls Street");
    map1.put("similarity", "0.945");

    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("name", "Wall Street");
    map2.put("point", "Walldd Street");
    map2.put("similarity", "0.871");

    HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("name", "Duck Street");
    map3.put("point", "Ducks duck");
    map3.put("similarity", "0.765");

    HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
    map4.put("name", "Duck Street");
    map4.put("point", "yelow duck");
    map4.put("similarity", "0.563");

    res.add(map1);
    res.add(map2);
    res.add(map3);
    res.add(map4);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Streams – How to group by value and find min and max value of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377851/java-streams-how-to-group-by-value-and-find-min-and-max-value-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

Some changes to solution provided by @Falah

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = res.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map->map.get("name")))
                                .entrySet().stream().map(m -> m.getValue().stream()
                                        .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> Double.parseDouble(s.get("similarity")))).get())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. Grouping by name
2. Getting max similarity value from each group

Answer (score 0):

Group it by the name first then the max similarity

```
        List<Map.Entry<String, Optional<HashMap<String, String>>>> result = res.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                       map -> map.get("name"),
                       Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(o -> Double.parseDouble(o.get("similarity"))))
               )).entrySet().stream().toList();


        result.forEach((map) -> {
            System.out.print("Max similarity of  " + map.getKey() + " is : ");
            map.getValue().ifPresent(System.out::println);
        });
```