# Sorting a HashMap and collecting it to a list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I came across this answer while trying to sort my hash map and collect it to a List:

[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values/23846961#23846961)

I tried this:

```
return myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (k,v) -> k, LinkedList::new));
```

However, I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'LinkedList'
```

All I want to do is collect my keys into a list after sorting my HashMap by values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` take no arguments. Probably you're seeing other error.  Alex and Efimov answers are correct, just use `toList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no parameters for `Collectors.toList()` as you should see...
So, you got stream of entries, you want map entries to keys, you should use `map`.

```
        myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Resulted list will be sorted (the list will keep its insertion order?)

Comment: Yes. Resulted list will be sorted (the list will keep its insertion order).

Comment: You can read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29216588/9809131
`Some intermediate operations, such as sorted(), may impose an encounter order on an otherwise unordered stream`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just map the entry to key after sorting?

```
return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // stream of keys
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```