# Convert Stream<A> into Stream<B> using "B map(A a1,A a2)"

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Stream<A>` of `n+1`elements and a functions `B map(A a1,A a2)` which takes two elements of `A` and returns one element of `B`. Now I want to get a `Stream<B>` of `n`elements such that the `i`-th element of the new stream is the result of `map(a[i],a[i+1])` (here I used the square brackets of course informally). How would you do that?

**Bonus:** Is there even a more general solution which converts a `Stream<A>` of `n-m+1`elements using a function `B map(A a1,A a2,...,A am)` to a `Stream<B>` of `n`elements?

Comment: Where do you get the `Stream<A>` from? Do you start from an array or a collection of As?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20507988/2891664 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30089904/2891664. (Which could also be generalized.)

Answer (score 4):

Well you can use my library [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) which has a function exactly to solve your first task:

```
Stream<A> src = //...
Stream<B> res = StreamEx.of(src).pairMap(this::map);
```

Internally there's a custom [spliterator](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/PairSpliterator.java) behind this function. So if you don't want an additional dependency, you can just implement similar spliterator in your project.

I did not implement more general solution for bonus task due to many reasons. However there's a similar function in [protonpack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codepoetics/protonpack/WindowedSpliterator.java) library. Via this library your task can be solved as:

```
Stream<B> res = StreamUtils.windowed(src, 2).map(l -> map(l.get(0), l.get(1)));
```

It cannot parallelize though. My spliterator parallelizes pretty well.

Comment: Using protonpack, it should looks like  `StreamUtils.windowed(Stream.of(1, 2, 3), 2).map(l -> map(l.get(0), l.get(1))).forEach(System.out::println);` which outputs, for example, `1_2` and `2_3` if the map function is `return a1+"_"+a2;` And it should works for the OP "Bonus" interrogation as well, by adjusting the window's size parameter.

Comment: Added protonpack code example. Yes, I meant that protonpack can solve the bonus task. I focus on performance and parallelism, so I dislike creating intermediate lists.