# Stateful filter for ordered stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem and I wonder if there is a solution using Streams.

Imagine you have an **ordered** stream of Objects; let's assume a stream of Integers.

```
 Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(2,20,18,17,4,11,13,6,3,19,4,10,13....)
```

Now I want to filter all values where the difference of a value and the previous number before this value is greater than *n*.

```
stream.filter(magicalVoodoo(5))
// 2, 20, 4, 11, 3, 19, 4, 10 ...
```

I there any possibility to do this?

Comment: can you change `Stream` with a `List` for example? things would be very much simpler in such a case

Comment: "No, this is not possible using streams, at least not easily. The stream API abstracts away from the order in which the elements are processed: the stream might be processed in parallel, or in reverse order. So "the next element" and "previous element" do not exist in the stream abstraction."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650157/is-it-possible-to-get-next-element-in-the-stream

Comment: @Eugene ATM this is what i do. But before and after this "filter" i work with streams. So to keep is "Pipeline Pattern " I would prefere a solution using streams.

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht Seems to be a valid reason, that this is not possible

Comment: btw let's take just the 3 first numbers from your output, why is `2` and `4` there? care to explain?

Comment: so you want actually *pair* of those?

Comment: I want to filter all values where the difference is greater than 5 (in absolut).
2-20=-18 (keep 20)
20-18=2 (remove 18)
20-17=3(remove 17)
20-4=16(keep 16)
4-11=-7(keep 11)
...

Comment: so the difference is *not* the previous, but the *next* and you also want absolute values now; and of course your description and your actual example make no sense what so ever

Comment: streams are absolutely not for this, this question is truly about some for loops and a while most probably

Comment: @Eugene You can absolutely use streams for this, as long as they are sequential streams and not parallel streams.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you could but it would be a bad idea to do so.  They're absolutely not _designed_ for this use case.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel stateful predicate, I think we can stop here  I would not use it...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Citation needed. It is possible, and if you assert the stream used is sequential it will work just fine.

Comment: @Eugene That it is not a functional pure solution and goes against your taste, does not mean it is not possible though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel exactly, that is why I said *I*, I actually like your solution btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you will need a stateful predicate that keeps track of the previous value for doing the comparison. This does mean it can only be used for sequential streams: with parallel streams you'd run into race conditions.

Luckily, most streams default to sequential, but if you need to do this on streams from an unknown source, you may want to check using `isParallel()` and either throw an exception, or convert it to a sequential stream using `sequential()`.

An example:

```
public class DistanceFilter implements IntPredicate {

    private final int distance;
    private int previousValue;

    public DistanceFilter(int distance) {
        this(distance, 0);
    }

    public DistanceFilter(int distance, int startValue) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.previousValue = startValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(int value) {
        if (Math.abs(previousValue - value) > distance) {
            previousValue = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Just for simple demonstration
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = IntStream.of(2, 20, 18, 17, 4, 11, 13, 6, 3, 19, 4, 10, 13)
                .filter(new DistanceFilter(5))
                .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    }
}
```

I used `IntStream` here, because it is a better type for this, but the concept would be similar for `Stream<Integer>` (or other object types).

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not designed for this kind of task. I would use a different way to accomplish this, which doesn't use streams. But, if you really must use streams, the solution has to circumvent certain restrictions due to the design of streams and lambdas, and therefore looks quite hacky:

```
int[] previous = new int[1];
previous[0] = firstElement;
... = stream.filter(n -> {
        boolean isAllowed = (abs(n - previous[0]) > 5);
        if (isAllowed)
            previous[0] = n;
        return isAllowed;})
```

Notice that the variable `previous` is a one-element array. That's a hack due to the fact that the lambda is not allowed to modify variables (it can modify an element of an array, but not the array itself).

Comment: You don't **need** to use lambdas with streams. You can also use objects implementing a predicate (eg `IntPredicate`).