# Extract Lines Between two timestamps in Log file using java

Tags: java, logging, data-extraction

I have log file which I should extract the data for particular duration and printed. I have to print lines between "2021-07-05 06:30:10" to "2021-07-05 06:30:20".

```
Files
.lines(Paths.get("c:/Java_Dev", "Abc.log"))
.filter(line -> line.startsWith("2021-07-05 06:30:10"))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here, It is printing the lines only staring with that time not a in between range.

Comment: Do you understand why the code you have now doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stateful filter for ordered stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761108/stateful-filter-for-ordered-stream)