# Peek the next Element in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to peek the next element in a stream? The idea rose from a stream of a list of objects, where two following objects should be compared (to smooth some diffs, but that shouldn't matter here). As an old `for` loop this would look like:

```
List<Car> autobahn = getCars();
for (int i = 0; i < autobahn.size()-1; i++) {
    if(autobahn.get(i).speed>autobahn.get(i+1).speed)
        autobahn.get(i).honk();
}
```

The best way so far as stream would be:

```
autobahn.stream()
            .limit(autobahn.size()-1)
            .filter(car -> car.speed < autobahn.get(autobahn.indexOf(car)+1).speed)
            .forEach(car -> car.honk());
```

The main-problem with this solution is the `indexOf` method, since there might be twice the same car on the autobahn. A better solution would be some way to peek the next (or the one before) element (with an helping class, this might be even possible, but looks horrible)

```
BoxedCar boxedCar = new BoxedCar(autobahn.get(0));
autobahn.stream()
            .skip(1)
            .filter(car -> boxedCar.setContent(car))
            .forEach(car -> car.winTheRace());
```

with helperclass

```
class BoxedCar {

    Car content;

    BoxedCar(Car content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    boolean setContent(Car content) {
        double speed = this.content.speed;
        this.content = content;
        return content.speed > speed;
    }
}
```

or to divert the `Stream<Car>` into a kind of `Stream<(Car,Car)>` with the second stream somehow created by the first one (this sounds also awful and here I have no idea, how this would look).

Is there a nice way to do this with streams, or are we stuck to the `for`-loop?

Comment: The for loop is not ridiculous at all. Actually, this is probably the cleaner code you'll be able to write for this. You could always use a Stream over the indexes but that's it.

Comment: @Tunaki I said, the streams would look ridiculous, not the for-loop. So far I also stick with the for-loop for obvious reasons. I am just wondering, if there is a nice possibility to achieve this also with streams. Edit, you can understand that part wrong, I delete it.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood sorry.

Comment: No, there isn't a good way to do it with streams; streams are not designed to be used for this sort of operation.

Comment: Actually, honking because the car before you is slower than yours is an abuse of the warning signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking with the `for` loop wouldn't be a bad idea. The Stream API isn't designed for this type of requirement. You can refer to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20507988/1743880) for more insight.

However, a simple way to do this using the Stream API would be to use a Stream over the indexes of your list, supposing that you have random access.

```
IntStream.range(0, autobahn.size() - 1)
         .filter(i -> autobahn.get(i).speed > autobahn.get(i+1).speed)
         .forEach(i -> autobahn.get(i).honk());
```

Note that this highly resemble the `for` loop.

Comment: Resembles the `for` loop but makes parallel processing possible.

Comment: As @ErickG.Hagstrom mentioned, this might has a better performance. Somehow I just oversaw this elegant and simple solution. Also the link has some interesting answers to this aspect. I am not sure, if this answer is actually faster in my use-case (LinkedList), but it definitly satisfies my question.

Comment: @ctst If you have a `LinkedList`, this is definitely not the good answer, performance-wise. A LinkedList does not have random access so accessing by index is disastrous. In that case, it would be better to first convert to an `ArrayList`, or use a for loop with an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Using my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
StreamEx.of(autobahn)
        .pairMap((car, nextCar) -> car.speed < nextCar.speed ? car : null)
        .nonNull()
        .forEach(Car::honk);
```

Here non-standard [`pairMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#pairMap-java.util.function.BiFunction-) operation is used which can map the adjacent pair of elements to the single element. This works for any stream source (not only random-access indexed list) and can be parallelized pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

what about using an `IntStream` instead of a loop:

```
IntStream.range(0, autobahn.size() - 1)
        .filter(i -> autobahn.get(i).speed < autobahn.get(i + 1).speed)
        .forEach(i -> autobahn.get(i).honk());
```