# Java Convert List<String> to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, java-stream

Is there a nice way to convert/transform a list of Strings (with Collectos API?) into a HashMap?

StringList and Map:

```
List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

...

My StringList contains Strings like:

```
    entries.add("id1");
    entries.add("name1, district");
    entries.add("id2");
    entries.add("name2, city");
    entries.add("id3");
    entries.add("name3");
```

**Output** should be:

```
{id1=name1, district, id2=name2, city, id3=name3}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just iterate over the list (in steps of 2) and put everything inside the map. It's only two lines of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need an external library, it's pretty easy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i += 2) {
  map.put(entries.get(i), entries.get(i+1));
}
```

Or, a more efficient way with non-random access lists would be:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = entries.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  map.put(it.next(), it.next());
}
```

Or, using streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, entries.size() / 2)
    .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(entries.get(2*i), entries.get(2*i+1))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: this definitely answers the OP, but I say the question is XY problem to be begin with

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!

I also tried the first two options. I was wondering if there is another way, like your third solution.

Comment: @Malsor the first two options are preferable to the third: they are clear, efficient and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer definitely works and it's a nice three liner, however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream/20507988#20507988) might explain how to do it with Stream API).

Comment: You can [link directly to specific answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20507988/3788176) (use the "share" link under the specific answers.