# Java 8+ stream: Check if list is in the correct order for two fields of my object-instances

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, boolean-expression

The title may be a bit vague, but here is what I have (in privatized code):

A class with some fields, including a BigDecimal and Date:

```
class MyObj{
  private java.math.BigDecimal percentage;
  private java.util.Date date;
  // Some more irrelevant fields

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

In another class I have a list of these objects (i.e. `java.util.List<MyObj> myList`). What I want now is a Java 8 stream to check if the list is in the correct order of both dates and percentages for my validator.

For example, the following list would be truthy:

```
[ MyObj { percentage = 25, date = 01-01-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 50, date = 01-02-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 100, date = 15-04-2019 } ]
```

But this list would be falsey because the percentage aren't in the correct order:

```
[ MyObj { percentage = 25, date = 01-01-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 20, date = 01-02-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 100, date = 15-04-2019 } ]
```

And this list would also be falsey because the dates aren't in the correct order:

```
[ MyObj { percentage = 25, date = 10-03-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 50, date = 01-02-2018 },
  MyObj { percentage = 100, date = 15-04-2019 } ]
```

One possible solution might be creating `Pairs` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20507988/1682559) and then using an `!` and `.anyMatch` checking each individual `Pair<MyObj>`. But I don't really want to create a `Pair` class just for this purpose if possible.

Is there perhaps a way to use `.reduce` or something to loop over pairs of `MyObj` to check them? What would be the best approach here to check if all dates and percentages of the `MyObj` in my list are in the correct order using Java 8 stream?

Another possibility is perhaps sorting the list by date, and then checking if they are all in order of percentage, if that's easier than checking both fields are the same time. The same issue with comparing pairs of `MyObj` for the percentage still remains, though.

(PS: I will use it for a `com.vaadin.server.SerializablePredicate<MyObj> validator`, and I prefer a Java 8 lambda because I've also used some for the other validators, so it would be more in line with the rest of the code. The Java 8 lambda is more a preference than requirement in my question however.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want both fields to be primary keys in the sorting. That sounds impossible to me unless you combine them in some  way. I can't see how that would be possble. or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @JackFlamp as I understand it he just wants to check, i.e. dates or percentages being out of order could be possible but the validator should report them as invalid.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how exactly you'd use `SerializablePredicate` (which btw isn't a JDK class)? I'm not sure you really _have_ to use a stream.

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you want to perform the sort? - or just validate that the existing order satisfies your requirements?

Comment: Sorry for the late responses, I was lunching. @JackFlamp As mentioned by _Thomas_, I only want to check if all the Dates are in the correct order and if all the Percentages are in the correct order as well. Can even be two separated validators, although I prefer one.

Comment: @Thomas Ah, you're right, the `com.vaadin.server.SerializablePredicate` is from the Vaadin Framework. Vaadin is a Java framework for web development, using GWT under the hood. I basically want to add a validator to a Vaadin Binder, which requires the `SerializablePredicate`.

Comment: @tbsalling No, I don't want to perform a sort. I just want to validate whether the list is corrected ordered for both dates and percentages.

Comment: @Holger It's more want than need tbh. I've already got a few other validators, like checking if the percentage 100 is present, and checking whether there aren't any duplicated percentage/date combination. Both of those use a Java 8 lambda, so that's why it would look better with another lamba for this check. It's more a preference than a requirement in my question.

Comment: So you want the sequence of percentages and the sequence of dates to be non-decreasing? I don't know why you started talking about sorting which has nothing to do with validating this and, as others have pointe dout, is impossible with this kind of comparison when certain elements are in the sequence.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I've removed the section about the sorting since it only seems to confuse readers. You're indeed right I only want to validate if both the percentages and dates are non-decreasing in my list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well if you want a short-circuiting operation, I don't think an easy solution using stream-api exists... I propose a simpler one, first define a method that in a short-circuiting way will tell you if your List is sorted or not, based on some parameter:

```
 private static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> boolean isSorted(List<T> list, Function<T, R> f) {
    Comparator<T> comp = Comparator.comparing(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; ++i) {
        T left = list.get(i);
        T right = list.get(i + 1);
        if (comp.compare(left, right) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And calling it via:

```
 System.out.println(
          isSorted(myList, MyObj::getPercentage) && 
          isSorted(myList, MyObj::getDate));
```

Comment: `if(comp.compare(left, right) < 0) { continue; } else { return false; }`, really? Why not `if(comp.compare(left, right) >= 0) { return false; }`?

Comment: Actually, it should only be `if(comp.compare(left, right) > 0) return false;`, as equal elements do not violate the sorted property. What’s the purpose of returning a `Supplier<Boolean>` instead of a `boolean`?

Comment: @Holger I thought that you write `boolean left = isSorted(...)` and `boolean right = isSorted(...); Syso(left && right)`, both of the booleans would have to be computed, potentially traversing the list twice

Comment: But you can simply write `isSorted(...) && isSorted(...)` instead, *if you really want this*, as `isSorted(x.thenComparing(y))` is not the same as `isSorted(x) && isSorted(y)`.

Comment: @Holger in your part are you implying that `isSorted` should really be defined as `private static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> Supplier<Boolean> isSorted(List<T> list, Function<T, R> f) {...}`?

Comment: I was misguided by the OP’s comparator example. Actually, `isSorted(...) && isSorted(...)` is intended. I don’t see any reason to use a `Supplier` here. Alternatively, you may accept a `BiPredicate` instead of a `Comparator`, to let the caller provide a function which checks both properties.

Comment: A nice and simple one! +1

Comment: @Holger may be, I am still inclined to provide a `Function` instead of a `Comparator` probably, it looks clearer to me. The `Supplier` is probably not needed, agreed, but it gives *me* an impression of being more clear. May be I'll change my mind after reading this one tomorrow.

Comment: I’d consider something like `static <T> boolean check(List<T> list, BiPredicate<T,T> p) { if(list.size() > 2) { T prev = list.get(0); for(T next: list.subList(1, list.size())) { if(!p.test(prev, next)) return false; prev = next; } } return true; }` which can be called like `check(myList, (a,b) -> comparator1.compare(a, b)<=0 && comparator2.compare(a, b)<=0)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I've put your method in my `StreamHelper` util class and used it as you suggested. Only small change I've made is using `BooleanSupplier` and `getBooleanValue()` instead of `Supplier<Boolean>` and `get()`, but that's basically equivalent to each other. Accepted as the answer, thanks again. EDIT: Hmm, your edited snippet looks even better, thanks again! :)

Comment: Having a `Supplier<Boolean>` is useless in this case since you evaluate the whole list to create that supplier, and evaluating the supplier is basically free (a constant value is returned). It just makes everything less readable. I don't think that part of the answer should be kept.

Comment: @DidierL oh shoot, good catch! That missed the point entirely of what I wanted to do initially with the `Supplier...` thank u

Comment: Does `IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1).map(i -> comp.compare(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1)).noneMatch(i -> i >= 0)` match the logic of your for-loop? (I'm not sure what would happen if `.parallel().unordered()` is used here.)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are almost there by trying to use `Stream.anyMatch`. You can accomplish it like this:

```
private static boolean isNotOrdered(List<MyObj> myList) {
    return IntStream.range(1, myList.size()).anyMatch(i -> isNotOrdered(myList.get(i - 1), myList.get(i)));

}

private static boolean isNotOrdered(MyObj before, MyObj after) {
    return before.getPercentage().compareTo(after.getPercentage()) > 0 ||
            before.getDate().compareTo(after.getDate()) > 0;
}
```

We can use `IntStream.range` to iterate over the elements of the list using an index. This way we can refer to any element in the list, e.g. the previous to compare it.

**EDIT** adding a more generic version:

```
private static boolean isNotOrderedAccordingTo(List<MyObj> myList, BiPredicate<MyObj, MyObj> predicate) {
    return IntStream.range(1, myList.size()).anyMatch(i-> predicate.test(myList.get(i - 1), myList.get(i)));
}
```

This can be called as follows using the above predicate:

```
isNotOrderedAccordingTo(myList1, (before, after) -> isNotOrdered(before, after));
```

Or using method reference in a class `ListNotOrdered`:

```
isNotOrderedAccordingTo(myList1, ListNotOrdered::isNotOrdered)
```

Comment: You can even omit the `myList.size() > 1 &&` part, as `anyMatch` on the empty stream will already do the right thing.

Comment: @Holger If the list has size 1, `anyMatch` will work but the inner call to `myList.get(i)` will cause an AIOOB exception. It is necessary for the list to have at least size 2 for this to work.

Comment: @LuisG. No, just try it, if you don’t believe. `IntStream.range(0, 1)` and `IntStream.range(1, 1)` are empty streams, which will never call `get` on the `List`.

Comment: Verified @Holger's suggestion. It applies to an empty list and a list with one element.

Comment: I ended up using _Eugene_'s approach because it's generic and easier re-usable for other streams. Just verified your approach however, and it's also working like a charm, so I've upvoted. Thanks as well for answering.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Since a genric solution is more appropriate for you I've update my answer adding a more generic version.

Comment: @Holger Cool, TIL :)

Comment: @LuisG. Oh - I see Holger wrote a comment using a `BiPredicate`. Hence it can not be wrong.:)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've mentioned that you wouldn't want to create a separate class `Pairs` for this, You can use an inbuilt class for such purpose: `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

You can make a `BiPredicate` which checks for both your comparing conditions & use that to compare all the pairs.

```
BiPredicate<MyObj,MyObj> isIncorrectOrder = (o1,o2) -> {
    boolean wrongOrder = o1.getDate().after(o2.getDate());
    return wrongOrder ? wrongOrder : o1.getPercentage().compareTo(o2.getPercentage()) > 0;
};

boolean isNotSorted =  IntStream.range(1,myObjs.size())
        .anyMatch(i -> isIncorrectOrder.test(myObjs.get(i-1),myObjs.get(i)));
```

---

The above solution with comparator:

```
Comparator<MyObj> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    boolean wrongOrder = o1.getDate().after(o2.getDate());
    return wrongOrder ? 1 : o1.getPercentage().compareTo(o2.getPercentage());
};

Predicate<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<MyObj,MyObj>> isIncorrectOrder = pair ->  comparator.compare(pair.getKey(),pair.getValue()) > 0;

boolean isNotSorted =  IntStream.range(1,myObjs.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(myObjs.get(i-1),myObjs.get(i)))
         .anyMatch(isIncorrectOrder);
```

Comment: I mainly meant creating a `Pair` class only for this purpose. Using a `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` as pair like you do is completely fine by me, so upvoted as well. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Provided an even smaller solution with `BiPredicate `

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution by `pairMap` in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(1, 2, 3, 5).pairMap((a, b) -> a <= b).allMatch(e -> e); // true

StreamEx.of(1, 2, 5, 3).pairMap((a, b) -> a <= b).allMatch(e -> e); // false

// your example:
StreamEx.of(myList)
   .pairMap((a, b) -> a.getPercentage().compareTo(b.getPercentage()) <= 0 && !a.getDate().after(b.getDate()))
   .allMatch(e -> e);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a problem that should be solved using streams. Streams apply mappings and filterings to the elements of a collection independently (probably even distributing the treatment of different elements to different CPU cores) before collecting them into a new collection again or reducing them to some sort of accumulated value. Your problem involves relations between different elements of a collection which contradicts the purpose of a stream. While there may be solutions involving streams those would be like hammering a nail into the wall with pliers. A classic loop will be perfectly fine for you: find the first occurence of an element breaking the order and return the desired result! Thus you wouldn't even need to create a pair.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `reduce` to compare two items (though it is not the best option). You just need to create a new "empty" item as a result when you find an item out of order, like this:

```
    boolean fullyOrdered = myList.stream()
            .reduce((a, b) -> {
                if ((a.percentage == null && a.date == null) || // previous item already failed 
                        a.percentage.compareTo(b.percentage) > 0 || // pct out of order
                        a.date.after(b.date)) { // date out of order
                    return new MyObj(null, null); // return new empty MyObj
                } else {
                    return b;
                }
            })
            .filter(a -> a.percentage != null || a.date != null)
            .isPresent();

    System.out.println("fullyOrdered = " + fullyOrdered);
```

This will print `true` only if both of your conditions are satisfied, `false` otherwise.

Of course, you could make the code nicer by including some auxiliary methods in `MyObj`:

```
class MyObj {
    // ...
    public MyObj() {}
    public static MyObj EMPTY = new MyObj();
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return percentage == null && date == null;
    }
    public boolean comesAfter(MyObj other) {
        return this.percentage.compareTo(other.percentage) > 0 ||
               this.date.after(other.date);
    }
}
// ...
        boolean fullyOrdered = myList.stream()
                .reduce((a, b) -> (a.isEmpty() || a.comesAfter(b)) ? MyObj.EMPTY : b)
                .filter(b -> !b.isEmpty())
                .isPresent();

        System.out.println("fullyOrdered = " + fullyOrdered);
```

---

Bear in mind that this is not short-circuiting, i.e. it will traverse the whole list even after it finds an unordered item. The only way to get out of the stream early while using `reduce` would be to throw a `RuntimeException` the moment you find the first unordered item, and that would be using exceptions to control program flow, which is considered bad practice. Still, I wanted to show you that you can indeed use `reduce` for this purpose.

For a short-circuiting approach that will finish as soon as it finds the first out of place item, take a look at @LuCio's answer.

Comment: This might not work for a parallel stream and breaks the reduce method contract because the accumulator is not associative.

Comment: @Alex Fair points. As I said, this was just kind of a PoC showing that yeah, you can do that using `reduce`, though other answers are better.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @luis g.'s answer, you can also use `reduce` in combination with `Optional` (empty means unsorted) and a "minimal" `MyObj` as the identity:

```
 boolean isSorted = list.stream()
            .map(Optional::of)
            .reduce(Optional.of(new MyObj(BigDecimal.ZERO, Date.from(Instant.EPOCH))),
                    (left, right) -> left.flatMap(l -> right.map(r -> l.date.compareTo(r.date)<= 0 && l.percentage.compareTo(r.percentage) <= 0 ? r : null)))
            .isPresent();
```

Note that the accumulating function (`BinaryOperator`) should be associative, which it is not in this case. Furthermore it is also not short-circuiting.