# Java filter list to only include distinct (Comparator does not return null for any pair of values) values

Tags: java

I created a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for a specific class. With this, I could easily sort lists (respectively streams) of this class.

In my case, I need to know if there are pairs of objects that are "equal" in the sense of the Comparator. Is there a easy way to get an list of "distinct" objects, or to know if there are "equal" objects?

The Comparator counts the number of null values in fields. So I want to know or filter objects with same number of null values.

Comment: Is your `compare()` method consistent with `equals()` and `hashCode()`? I guess not, but if it were, I usually deal with this by creating a HashSet and checking return value of add().

Comment: no it is not.  in most cases if comparator yields 0 the objects won't be equal.Updated my question

Comment: Without exposing hidden information(number of null values), this problem will have a complexity of `n^2`(checking every pair), there's no way around it I fear. To make it faster, you might expose a function which returns number of nulls and then the check is pretty straightforward(the trick with HashSet can be used).

Comment: So your `Comparator` sorts your list based on the number of null values in fields and I guess items with equal number of null values will be adjacent right? It seems to me that with a single pass, checking each item and the next one you can skip "equal" items.

Comment: in first step i have to sort them using the comparator. and after that i want to know/ filter all pairs that yield 0 in comparison - yes after sorting they should be adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

Use [StreamEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream) to collect pairs from a stream and be able to pass a BiPredicate

Then pass a bipredicate to filter your data :

```java
Comparator<Object> yourComparator = ...;
BiPredicate<Object,Object> bip = (d1,d2) -> comp.compare(d1,d2) == 0;
List<Object> data = ...;

List<Object> result = data.stream().pairMap(bip).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: for an example i would probably upvote - at the moment i am not sure if i want to introduce this dependency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream

Comment: yes i saw it - and thanks for the link. But the answer is not specific to my question.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as completed or ask any question about it :)