# List of sorted dates to blocks in Java

Tags: java, list, date, sorting, datetime

I have a list of sorted OffsetDateTime dates:

```
[2021-05-21T11:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00, 2021-05-21T17:00-04:00]
```

I'd like to create a list of objects with a start and end date like the following:

{start: 2021-05-21T11:00-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00}

{start: 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00, end: 2021-05-21T17:00-04:00}

Note that the start of the next date is the end of the previous date (Except first and last)

What I have so far...

```
    // Create List<AppointmentAvailabilityBlock>
    List<AppointmentAvailabilityBlock> appointmentAvailabilityBlockList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedTimes.size(); i+=2) {
        
        OffsetDateTime start = sortedTimes.get(i);
        OffsetDateTime end = sortedTimes.get(i+1);
        appointmentAvailabilityBlockList.add(new AppointmentAvailabilityBlock(start, end));
        
    }
```

But this outputs:

2021-05-21T11:00-04:00 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00

2021-05-21T13:00-04:00 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00

2021-05-21T15:00-04:00 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00

2021-05-21T15:45-04:00 2021-05-21T17:00-04:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options that you could use depending on whether you wanted to store the results or print them.  Before that, here are some points to consider:

- in the provided answers, `.collect(Collectors.toList())` may be replaced with `.forEach(System.out::println)` if all you want is to print them.  The assignment to the list result must also be removed.
- `List.subList` comes in handy here. But each `subList` is simply a view into the original list.  So any changes to `subList` will change the original. This can be solved by passing the `subList` as an argument to `ArrayList<>()`
- the results shown are based on the default toString display for `OffsetDateTime`.  To change that you can apply a `DateTimeFormatter` within the stream construct.

Just print the values in pairs using a `stream` and a `subList`

```
IntStream.range(1, sortedTimes.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> sortedTimes.subList(i - 1, i + 1))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[2021-05-21T11:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00]
[2021-05-21T12:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00]
[2021-05-21T13:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00]
[2021-05-21T14:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00]
[2021-05-21T15:00-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00]
[2021-05-21T15:30-04:00, 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00]
[2021-05-21T15:45-04:00, 2021-05-21T17:00-04:00]
```

Storing the pairs in a List of lists to be processed later.  The `subList` was passed to an `ArrayList` as explained above.

```
List<List<OffsetDateTime>> list = IntStream
        .range(1, sortedTimes.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<>(sortedTimes.subList(i - 1, i + 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A little more elaborate printing and storing in a list.

```
List<String> listString = IntStream.range(1, sortedTimes.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> sortedTimes.subList(i - 1, i + 1))
        .map(s->"Start: " + s.get(0) + " - End: " + s.get(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.forEach(System.out.println);
```

Prints

```
Start: 2021-05-21T11:00-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T12:00-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T13:00-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T14:00-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T15:00-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T15:30-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00
Start: 2021-05-21T15:45-04:00 - End: 2021-05-21T17:00-04:00
```

And just for completion, here is how the `List<OffsetDateTime>` was created

```
List<String> sortedStringTimes = new ArrayList<>(List.of("2021-05-21T11:00-04:00",
                "2021-05-21T12:00-04:00", "2021-05-21T13:00-04:00",
                "2021-05-21T14:00-04:00", "2021-05-21T15:00-04:00",
                "2021-05-21T15:30-04:00", "2021-05-21T15:45-04:00",
                "2021-05-21T17:00-04:00"));

DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

// toList() as used below was introduced in Java 16
List<OffsetDateTime> sortedTimes = sortedStringTimes.stream()
        .map(odt->OffsetDateTime.from(df.parse(odt))).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void createObjects(List<OffsetDateTime> dates){
   for(int i=0;i<dates.size()-1;i++){
     Pair<OffsetDateTime, OffsetDateTime> date = new Pair<>(dates.get(i), dates.get(i+1));
     // handle each object as you require
     call_my_function(date);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to fix your own code, you should do i++ in the for loop instead of i+=2

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna use a more modern approach via streams. You could find a better solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream).

In short, your code might looks like the next:

```java
 IntStream.range(1, sortedTimes.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> new AppointmentAvailabilityBlock(sortedTimes.get(i-1), sortedTimes.get(i)))
             .forEach(System.out::println)
```